# Implementing a safe ValueQ that does not evaluate its argument

Tags: evaluation, expression-test

*Mathematica* has a built-in function `ValueQ`. Quoting the docs,

> `ValueQ[expr]` gives `True` if a value has been defined for `expr`, and gives `False` otherwise.
>
> ...
>
> `ValueQ` gives `False` only if `expr` would not change if it were to be entered as *Mathematica* input.

This works nicely with symbols that only have `OwnValues`:

```
x = Print["boo!"]
ValueQ[x]

(* ==> True *)
```

It doesn't work so nicely with functions, though:

```
f[x_] := Print[x]
ValueQ[f[1]]

(*
     1
 ==> True
*)
```

This gives `True`, but also evaluates `f[1]` completely, printing `1`.  This is clearly dangerous, and it is important to be aware of this.  Unfortunately, the docs make no mention of this under the "Possible Issues" section!

Why this happens is clear if we look at the implementation of `ValueQ` for non-symbols:

```
ValueQ[expr_] := ! Hold[Evaluate[expr]] === Hold[expr]
```

**Question:** Is it possible to implement a more robust version of `ValueQ`, which does not evaluate its argument in an unexpected an possibly dangerous way?

Comment: This is especially weird since `ValueQ` has the atttribute `HoldAll`. Maybe you discovered a bug?

Comment: @David `HoldAll` attribute only says what will happen to the function's arguments *before* they are passed to the function, but nothing about how the function itself evaluates them. A situation when function is not supposed to evaluate arguments passed to it but does that nonetheless, is called *evaluation leak*, and is something to watch out for when you develop `HoldAll` etc functions. For the case at hand, this was discovered before, perhaps more than once, e.g. [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4621562).

Comment: There are several ways to handle the meaning of `ValueQ`, as Leonid and I have been discussing.  I deleted my answer until I have time to consider all this and expand/revise accordingly.

Comment: @Leonid I am dissatisfied with the function in its current state; it's just too weird to get `True` for `Hold[2]` or `"a" + "b"` or `x[1][2]` (where `x` is undefined).  I am exploring another possibility now.

Comment: @Mr. Wizard I see.

Answer (score 17):

#### Preamble

This [has been discussed before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4599241/checking-if-a-symbol-is-defined), and this problem was also [identified and partially addressed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4599241/checking-if-a-symbol-is-defined/4621562#4621562) in the same question. I will use a slightly simpler implementation which also covers `UpValues`. It is probably not complete either, but it covers many common cases of interest.

#### Implementation

Here is the code:

```
ClearAll[symbolicHead];
SetAttributes[symbolicHead, HoldAllComplete];
symbolicHead[f_Symbol[___]] := f;
symbolicHead[f_[___]] := symbolicHead[f];
symbolicHead[f_] := Head[Unevaluated[f]];

ClearAll[valueQ];
SetAttributes[valueQ, HoldAllComplete];
valueQ[a_Symbol] /; OwnValues[a] =!= {} :=
    With[{result = (# =!= (# /. OwnValues[a])) &[HoldComplete[a]]},
       result /; result];

valueQ[a : f_Symbol[___]] /; DownValues[f] =!= {} :=
    With[{result = (# =!= (# /. DownValues[f])) &@HoldComplete[a]},
       result /; result];

valueQ[a_] :=
    With[{sub = SubValues[Evaluate[symbolicHead[a]]]},
      With[{result  = (# =!= (# /. sub)) &[HoldComplete[a]]},
          result /; result] /; sub =!= {}
    ];

valueQ[a_] :=
   With[{upsyms  =
       Flatten@Cases[Unevaluated[a], s_Symbol :> UpValues[s], 1, Heads -> True]},
          With[{result  = (# =!= (# /. upsyms)) &[HoldComplete[a]]},
             result /; result] /; upsyms =!= {}
   ];

valueQ[_] := False;
```

Symbolic heads are further discussed in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5958128/arbitrarily-deep-nested-pattern-matching/5961851#5961851). The order of definitions is important, and roughly corresponds to the order of steps applying those global rules,  in the main evaluation sequence.

#### Examples

```
a := Print["*"];
b[1] := Print["*"];
c[1][4] := Print["*"];
d /: f[x_Integer, d, y_Integer] := Print["*"];

valueQ /@ Unevaluated[{a, b[1], c[1][4], f[1, d, 2]}]

(*
  ==> {True, True, True, True}
*)
```

#### Limitations

I did not include the `NValues` (this can be done, but the question is whether we really want to do that). This seems to pretty much exhaust the set of things we can do without really evaluating an expression in question. In certain cases, the results will be different from `ValueQ`, for example:

```
{valueQ[N[Pi]],ValueQ[N[Pi]]}

(*
  ==> {False,True}
*)
```

#### Summary

The code above was not meant to be absolutely complete, and probably can not be, since not everything is exposed to the top-level / end user. But it is hoped that it covers many cases of interest, and can be further extended to cover some that it misses currently. Note that, since internal global rules are not available at the top-level, `valueQ` is mostly limited to user-defined or top-level functions and variables. If one wants to include system symbols with internal rules, I don't see other ways than allowing the expression to evaluate.

This may also explain (to some extent), why built-in `ValueQ` was written the way it was - to also cover the system symbols and be general. On a deeper level, this seems to reflect that the separation between internal and top-level rules is rather artificial and sometimes flies in the face of the core language semantics, particularly when one wants to write some general functions related to introspection, such as `ValueQ`.

Comment: This is probably obvious, but here is another case where `valueQ` and `ValueQ` differ: `{valueQ@{1 + 1}, ValueQ@{1 + 1}}`. Overall I think `valueQ` is much more useful.

Comment: @Ajasja Good point, thanks. Generally, picking one over another is a hard question, because there is no direct mapping between Mathematica evaluation sequence and our expectations of usefulness in this or that situation (evaluation sequence usually contains steps which we consider trivial and others we consider important, but from the system's viewpoint all steps have the same degree of importance. So, filtering out "trivial" evaluations is to a large degree a subjective matter). That said, I agree that more often than not I find `ValueQ` to not be appropriate for the task,  unlike `valueQ`.

Comment: Interestingly, under v8 and v9, `valueQ /@ Unevaluated[{a, b[1], c[1][5], f[1, d, 2]}]` returns `{True, True, False, True}` instead of four `True`-s. Did I miss something?

Comment: @IstvánZachar Thanks, you spotted a typo. Should have been `c[1][4]`. It is unclear to me how this leaked into the answer, usually I copy the output directly from Mathematica.  Will edit now.

Comment: Ah, ok, I assumed that it was deliberate to call with a different argument than in the definition.

Answer (score 15):

Using the core of my new [`step` function](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/1447/121):

```
SetAttributes[valueQ1, HoldAll]

valueQ1[expr_] :=
 Module[{P, R = False},
   P = (P = Return[R = True, TraceScan] &) &;
   TraceScan[P, expr, TraceDepth -> 1];
   R 
 ]

SetAttributes[valueQ2, HoldAll]

valueQ2[expr_] :=
 Module[{P, R = False},
   P = (P = Return[R = True, TraceScan] &) &;
   TraceScan[P, expr];
   R 
 ]

SetAttributes[valueQ3, HoldAll]

valueQ3[expr_] :=
  Block[{Print},
    TraceScan[
      Null &, expr, _,
      If[# =!= HoldForm[#2], Return[True, TraceScan]] &
    ] // TrueQ
  ]
```

---

*Long* overdue update.

`valueQ1` is my proposal for an alternative to `ValueQ` which leaks far *less* often.  In most cases it returns the same answer that `ValueQ` does.  It gives True if *the entire expression* is transformed in the course of evaluation.

`valueQ2` is a trigger-happy version of Q1 that returns `True` if *any* evaluation takes place for the given expression.  Leonid favors this one as being the most "pure" within *Mathematica's* framework, but it also makes for a lot of (arguably) false-positives.

`valueQ3` is an attempt to get behavior closer to `ValueQ` (than Q1), and no leaks, but it may not be robust.  The purpose of Blocking `Print` is *NOT* to hide the leaks (`i` below is used to check this), but a work-around because `Print` caused the method to fail; it is unknown to me what other function calls would also cause failure.

Here is a table of results for these functions compared to `ValueQ`:

```
ClearAll[a, b, c, d, f, g, gg, x];
i = 0;
a := Print["*a"];
b[1] := (i++; Print["*b"])
c[1][4] := (i++; Print["*c"])
d /: f[x_Integer, d, y_Integer] := (i++; Print["*d"])
gg[x_] := (i++; Print["*gg"]; False)
g[x_] /; gg[x] := x^2
x = 1;
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Results in red are tests that leaked.

Comment: `Trace` and friends *have to* evaluate the expression being traced, if I am not mistaken.

Comment: No I did not yet - my comment was just based on the general considerations. I will look into it.

Comment: Yes. For example, here: `valueQAlt[{b[1]}]` - it leaks evaluation.

Comment: This is not the point. The point is that we should be able to feed *any* expression into `valueQ`, and be sure that it won't be evaluated. Imagine using `valueQ` inside e.g. `Cases`, something like `Cases[Unevaluated[expr],sub_/;valueQ[sub]:>HoldComplete[sub],Infinity]`. In other words, at least in my interpretation, this question is in the first place about making `valueQ` with a well-defined and general evaluation semantics.

Comment: Well, take some `g[b[1]]` with undefined `g` in place of a `List`, if you wish - it then will make sense also in more narrow context.

Comment: This is what I am thinking myself about at the moment. If `valueQ[{f[1]}]` should give `False`, then your approach does not seem to work. But, alternatively, we may  define the semantics of `valueQ` such that it gives `True` whenever an expression *at all evaluates* if we let it - in this formulation, your approach works and my does not. So, the question is, which semantics is the "right" one. I would think that `valueQ[{f[1]}]` should return `False`, but this is not that clear-cut to me. *And*, your approach is both more elegant and more general than mine. So, I don't know, really.

Comment: Here is a problem though: `ClearAll[f, g];f[x_] := False;g[x_] /; f[x] := x^2;valueQ[g[1]]`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/2423/discussion-between-spartacus-and-leonid-shifrin)

Comment: @LeonidShifrin, can you explain why With[{x = {f}},valueQ[x]] gives a different result than With[{x := {f}},valueQ[x]] with Spartacus's valueQ? Some kind of internal optimization avoiding reevaluation of x? In any case, it's an inconsistent solution whatever the interpretation of valueQ if its result depend on internals such as this one

Comment: @Spartacus, the previous comment is for you too... I'm also willing to talk about this issue but there's probably no good solution

Comment: @Leonid let us delete these comments since they are archived in the chat (I'll leave that link).

Comment: @Rojo I realize that we never answered your question.  Factually it is because of the difference between `With[{x = {f}}, TracePrint[x]]` and `With[{x := {f}}, TracePrint[x]]` but that may not be the answer you were looking for.  It is my opinion that Leonid has a better grasp of the evaluation process to answer *why* there is this difference.  Also, have you had the chance to try my `valueQ3` yet?  It is quite experimental but I believe may be the best.  I have not updated my answer with a description of each as I want to talk to Leonid first.

Comment: @Spartacus, it works way better than the other one, nice. However, the thing with Print is just a lie, haha. It tries to prevent the user from learning that evaluations happen, but they still happen. Try valueQ3[x=8] and see how x gets the value. And, that lie has sideffects. Such as (contorted example) g[Null] := 8; g[Print[2]] returns 8, but valueQ[g[Print[2]]] gives False. So I think it's going great, but it would be better without the Block to Print, what do you think?

Comment: @Rojo I haven't spent any time on that today.  The purpose of `Block[{Print} . . .` was NOT to fake the tests but to deal with a problem I had with `TraceScan`.  See the chat log above for more.  Thank you for your testing an examples.  I shall try to see if the issues can be addressed or if this is destined to fail.

Comment: @Rojo the second example `g[Print[2]]` is easy to explain because it *relies* on `Print` which I specifically Blocked.  Consider that a corner case.  The case with `Set` is far more interesting, and concerning, because last night I *thought* that would be intercepted.

Comment: @Spartacus my bad then, not a lie (I didn't understand the particular issue with Print but it's ok). I honestly don't know how one could prevent all or most of the evaluations, hope you find a way. But I still consider it very useful if you prevent some of the evaluation while making it behave like the built in. And this version almost does that. So good job

Comment: @Rojo Thanks.  Slowly I am forming ideas about the utility of these functions.  Leonid's is more like a "HasDefinitionQ" than `ValueQ`.  My `valueQ1` is similar to `ValueQ` but leaks less (though it still leaks).  `valueQ2` is really more like a "NotInertQ".  The third function is experimental.  I see why something like `valueQ3[x = 8]` leaks (while `valueQ3[x = 2 + 2]` doesn't), and I am not confident that it can be made to work.  I think that I would have to compile a list of built-in "verbs" that specifically take action such as `Set` and `Print` and catch those *before* evaluation.

Comment: I don't think there's a way to implement the built-in's behaviour without leaking in many cases. Because how could you tell if a condition's evaluation is necessary to tell if it matches or is simply the function doing it's work as in `Print`, `Do`, etc?