# Different behaviour of ValueQ inside and outside of a loop

Tags: evaluation

I need to store a rather big number of variables and I tried to do that by storing each variable as Z[n] with varying n. I guess this was not my best idea. The first problem I encountered is when I tried to check whether Z[n] is set. As you can see at the picture if I do this inside a loop it is always true and outside a loop it is the correct value. Why is this happening? I have mathematica 8.0.4.0.

(I had no idea how should I have tagged the question. Feel free to change them.)

[image: Output]

Comment: Nice question, but please provide copyable code next time. Many people tend to skip questions that require them to type the code themselves.

Comment: Somewhat related [question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1474/implementing-a-safe-valueq-that-does-not-evaluate-its-argument)

Comment: Sjoerd you are absolutely right, I didn't think of that, I'll keep it in mind.

Leonid thank you for the link.

Comment: Have you thought about creating your variables with `z=Table[Unique[],{numVariables}]` then you can have `x[[1]],z[[2]],...` or `Table[Unique["z"],{numVariables}]` to give `z1,z2,z3,...`. Though the exact numbering of the latter depends upon the existence of any already defined `z`s.

Comment: It's not very convenient. I actually have a series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty z_n t^{-n}$ so the numbering and the order is very important for me. I don't really like the way I store the data, but works fairly well.

Comment: Is there any way to create algorithmically variables z1, z2, z3, etc with numbers I choose? The only other option I know is to use Subscript.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`ValueQ[Z[sindex]]` is equivalent to `!Hold[Evaluate[Z[sindex]]]===Hold[Z[sindex]]` which evaluates to `!(Hold[Z[1]]===Hold[Z[sindex]])`. Since lhs and rhs of the latter are not literally the same the result combined with `Not` is `True`.

This has nothing to do with being inside the loop or not. If you try `ValueQ[Z[sindex]]` outside the loop you get the same result. Note that you didn't test that, but instead assumed that `ValueQ[Z[1]]` would be equivalent. It's the presence of the '1' that makes the difference here.

The `ValueQ` documentation page provides a warning about this pitfall in the "Possible Issues" section:

> ValueQ returns True if any evaluation takes place

A workaround in this case would be the use of `With` to inject the actual value of `sindex` in the expression to be tested.

```
With[{sindex = sindex}, ValueQ[Z[sindex]]]
```

> False

Comment: Thank you very much, I wasted quite a few frustrating hour with this and yet I failed to check what ValueQ[Z[sindex]] evaluates to.