# Pass by reference for an option argument

Tags: function-construction, options

Pass by reference can be faked by using `HoldAll` or something similar in the definition of a "Function". But can pass by reference be faked for symbols passed as named arguments (Options)?

Let me demonstrate:

This works (when you click on the checkboxes the list changes):

```
ClearAll@PassByArg;
Attributes[PassByArg] = {HoldFirst};
PassByArg[list_] := CheckboxBar[Dynamic[list], Range@Length@list];
aList = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
PassByArg[aList]
Dynamic[Sort@aList]
```

**How can I pass the reference to `list` as an option?**

Here is one of my failed attempts (it returns `et::setraw: Cannot assign to raw object {1,2,3,4,5}` when a checkbox is clicked.

```
ClearAll@PassByOption;
Options@PassByOption = {"List" -> None};
PassByOption[opts : OptionsPattern[]] := 
  With[{i = ReleaseHold@OptionValue@"List"}, 
   CheckboxBar[Dynamic[i], Range@Length@i]];
aList = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
PassByOption["List" -> Hold@aList]
Dynamic[aList]
```

I always evaluate either too much (to `{1,2,3,4,5}`) or too little...

Perhaps some motivation is in order: I'm developing a GUI using `Dynamic`. Now I would like to control a list of displayed functions in some plot. If I implement this as a reference passed with a named argument I practically don't have to change any other code:)

Comment: Related: [How to modify function argument?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/17767/121)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is a case for [injector pattern](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1929/injecting-a-sequence-of-expressions-into-a-held-expression/1937#1937):

```
PassByOption[opts : OptionsPattern[]] :=
  OptionValue["List"] /. Hold[l_] :> CheckboxBar[Dynamic[l], Range@Length@l]
```

You can check that this works with this change.

As an alternative, you can by-pass the use of `Hold` and clever tricks like the above, by using the longer form of `OptionValue`:

```
ClearAll@PassByOptionAlt;
Options@PassByOptionAlt = {"List" -> None};
PassByOptionAlt[opts : OptionsPattern[]] :=
  OptionValue[
     PassByOptionAlt, 
     {opts}, 
     "List", 
     Function[l, CheckboxBar[Dynamic[l], Range@Length@l], HoldAll]
  ]
```

This will work too, but, as mentioned by Szabolcs in comments, you will need to use `RuleDelayed` (`:>`) to pass the symbol:

```
PassByOptionAlt["List" :> aList]
```

Comment: @Ajasja Always glad to help :). This question, by the way, should have been asked here long ago, since this is a common situation.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to do the job :

```
ClearAll@PassByOption;
Attributes[PassByOption] = {HoldFirst};
PassByOption[opts___] := 
  With[{list = Hold["List"] /. Unevaluated[{opts}], 
        length = Range[Length["List" /. {opts}]]
        }, 
      CheckboxBar[Dynamic[list], length] /. Hold[x_] -> x
      ];
aList = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
PassByOption["List" -> aList]
Dynamic[Sort@aList]
```

`Unevaluated` is used to prevent `aList` (from the option `"List" -> aList`) to be evaluated.

Warning : as `Attributes[PassByOption] = {HoldFirst}` the option `"List" -> aList` must be the first option when you call `PassByOption`

Answer (score 1):

Just for fun here is a way to pass the reference as a string
(I got this idea from @Leonids answer, but I'm not sure it brings anything useful over the injector pattern):

Here is the code:

```
ClearAll@PassByOptionStr;
Options@PassByOptionStr={"List"->None};
PassByOptionStr[opts:OptionsPattern[]]:=
    ToExpression[OptionValue["List"],InputForm, 
        Function[l, CheckboxBar[Dynamic[l], Range@Length@l]
    , HoldAll]]
```

Check that it works:

```
aList = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
PassByOptionStr["List" -> SymbolName@Unevaluated@aList]
Dynamic@aList
```

---

This is not directly related to the original question, but the next step is to test if the passed reference is valid. A convenient way to do this is using Leonids [`valueQ`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/1484/745) function. Apart from not leaking evaluations `valueQ` has some nice adavantages over the built in `ValueQ`. Compare for example:

```
{valueQ@{1 + 1}, ValueQ@{1 + 1}}

(* ==> {False, True} *)
```