# Behavior of ValueQ inside a function

Tags: functions, functional-style

The following code

```
Cases[Function[{x}, x + 1], a_?ValueQ :> Hold[a], ∞, Heads -> True]
```

unexpectedly returns

> {Hold[x + 1]}

According to the manual, "ValueQ[expr] gives True if a value has been defined for expr, and gives False otherwise."

In the example above, what is the expression that was assigned the value x+1?

Comment: You can use `Trace` to see that `ValueQ[expr]` is in fact `! Hold[Evaluate[expr]] === Hold[expr]`, and since `Evaluate[x+1]` is `1+x` it passes the test. It is strange to me, maybe someone else can confirm it's desired behaviour or a bug.

Comment: I recommend reading [this discussion](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1474/implementing-a-safe-valueq-that-does-not-evaluate-its-argument) and come comments / chat session linked there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The definition for `ValueQ` says

> gives `True` if a value has been defined for `expr`, and gives `False` otherwise.

So in this context you result is very strange. But later in `Details` section there is more conservative statement:

> `ValueQ` gives `False` **only if `expr` would not change** if it were to be entered as *Mathematica* input.

So even if it does look strange, almost a bug, it fits the description because *Mathematica* uses different order, as default, than traditional.

```
x + 1
```

> ```
> 1 + x
> ```