# Pattern matching to head with HoldFirst

Tags: evaluation, pattern-matching, hold

I want to define a function that only operates on expressions with a head from a given list, such as

```
f[expr:(_And|_Or)] := Print["LHS is ", expr[[1]]];
```

This of course works fine when `x` is just an expression such as `expr = p == q || p == q + 1`. However, now I'd like to be able to print out parts of `expr` even when p and q both have values defined. That is, if `f` and `expr` are defined as above, then

```
p = 1;
q = 2;
f[expr]
```

should print "LHS is True". The obvious thing to try is of course to add

```
SetAttributes[f, HoldFirst]
```

but now `f` doesn't match `expr`, i.e. `f[expr]` simply returns `f[expr]`. I've tried variations of this, but nothing I can come up with seems to work, `expr` is always either evaluated before matching the head or the correct head is not found.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With more complex patterns, and especially held values, you have to think carefully about how your expression will be resolved.

```
a := ( Print[ "a!" ] ; True ) ;
SetAttributes[ f , HoldFirst ] ;
f[ x_ /; x == True ] := x ;
f[ a ]
```

> a!
>
> a!
>
> True

Had `a` had been something like `p == q` and `p` and `q` had values, it would have been reduced to `True` or `False` each time, meaning you could not test for the `Head`. So why was it evaluated twice?

```
Unevaluated[ f[ x_ /; x == True ] := x ] // FullForm
```

> Unevaluated[ SetDelayed[ f[ Condition[ Pattern[ x , Blank[ ] ] , Equal[ **x** , True ] ] ] , **x** ] ]

There are 2 copies of `x` not inside a `Pattern`: one in the condition, and one on the right-hand side. So the trick is to block Mathematica's normal evaluation routine to protect your symbolic expressions.

Controlling evaluation is a broad topic; MrWizard recently recommended [this very helpful article](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/Courseware/377/) on the subject to me, which I in turn recommend.

In this case you can achieve that with:

```
ClearAll[ f , p , q ] ;
heads = Alternatives @@ ( Blank /@ { And , Or } ) ;
SetAttributes[ f , HoldFirst ] ;
f[ x_ ] := List @@ Unevaluated @ x /; MatchQ[ Unevaluated @ x, heads ] ;
f[ p == q || p == q + 1 ]
```

> { p == q , p == 1 + q }

```
p = 2 ;
q = 1 ;
f[ p == q || p == q + 1 ]
```

> { False , True }

```
f[ 1 + 2 ]
```

> f[ 1 + 2 ]

Depending on what exactly you're doing, it may be easier to approach the problem in this style, however:

```
ClearAll[ p , q ] ;
{ p == q , p == 1 + q } /. { p -> 2 , q -> 1 }
```

> { False , True }

Comment: Thanks for a thorough answer to my question, accepted! In case you're interested, what I'm trying to do is to make a debug function that allows me to do essentially `analyzeConditional[p == q || p == q+1]`, which would print "p == q is False", "p == q + 1 is True", and so on, decomposing the conditional at boolean operators and printing out each subcondition, and then finally returning the value of the whole conditional. The purpose is to debug a situation where an algorithm terminates at a reasonably complex combination of conditions, and I want to know at which subcondition.

Answer (score 1):

I propose using the `step` function I presented in:  [How do I evaluate only one step of an expression?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/334/how-do-i-evaluate-only-one-step-of-an-expression/1447#1447)
(For the remainder of this answer I will assume you have that function loaded.)

I wrote it for the purpose of handling delayed definitions such as:

```
expr := (p == q || p == q + 1)
```

You could use it in the following manner:

```
SetAttributes[f, HoldFirst]
f[expr : (_And | _Or)] :=
  (Print["LHS is ", Unevaluated[expr][[1]]];
   Print["RHS is ", Unevaluated[expr][[2]]])
f[expr_?ValueQ] := f @@ step[expr]
```

Now:

```
p = 2;
q = 1;
f[expr]
```

> LHS is False
>
> RHS is True

If the argument has an apparent head of `And` or `Or` the first definition is used.  If not `ValueQ` is used to check to see of the expression has a value, and if it does it is partially evaluated with `step` then passed back to `f` using `Apply`.  Note: `ValueQ` [can leak](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1474/121) side-effects but it is fine for basic purposes such as this.

See [Setting options of expressions similar to using SetOptions on objects](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/38827/setting-options-of-expressions-similar-to-using-setoptions-on-objects/46925#46925) for other examples.