# Pattern matching list of elements with different heads

Tags: list-manipulation, pattern-matching, head

I have a function, which I want to accept only a list of kind of elements belonging to a group. The task comes down to finding an elegant pattern suitable for easy to read function prototype.

As an example I have a pattern, which works:

```
pattern = {__?(Head[#] === foo || Head[#] === bar &)}
```

but I am sure, that it can be in a more elegant way.

Here are some cases were I expect the pattern to match the parameter:

```
MatchQ[{foo[a1], bar[b1, b2], foo[c1], bar[b1, b2]}, pattern]
MatchQ[{foo[a1]}, pattern]
```

And here I expect to get false:

```
MatchQ[{foo[a1], bar[b1, b2], cha[c1, c2]}, pattern]
MatchQ[{}, pattern]
MatchQ[{foo}, pattern]
MatchQ[{1}, pattern]
MatchQ[foo, pattern]
```

Weakly related to ["Pattern matching to head with holdfirst"](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/48943/pattern-matching-to-head-with-holdfirst).

Comment: I don't know if I'd call it more elegant, but you can use the `x_Head` notation and do `pattern = {__?(# /. y_foo | y_bar -> True &)}`. Is there any particular criterion you're interested in?

Comment: It is an alternative but I would not call it more elegant. Imagen a function prototype of the form `f[x : {__?(# /. y_foo | y_bar -> True &)}] := test[x]`, Hiding the pattern in some function `f[x : {__?patternTest}]` would not be much better, as then one needs to look up `pattern` to see the format.

Comment: So are you looking for a better way to write the pattern? You could also do 'pattern = {(foo|bar)[__]..}` which is more readable to me.

Comment: Or even more readable `pattern = {(_foo|_bar)..}`

Comment: Thanks! I guess it can not be short than this. Could you turn it to answer?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use the syntax for matching a head `_Head`, along with the alternative `|` symbol, and repeated `..` to do `pattern = {(_foo|_bar)..}`. Which should match any list containing only expressions with the heads foo, and bar in any order.