# Is there any way to use head of Real and Integer altogether?

Tags: pattern-matching, head

Is there any way to use the head of `Integer` and `Real` together like below?
The below is not right, I know that, it is just for showing my thought.

```
f[x_(Integer||Real)] := x^2
```

The reason I ask this is because I need a function that receives an argument which is either integer or real.

Comment: `x : (_Integer | _Real )`. Look up `Alternatives[]`.

Comment: `Integer` and `Real` are data types.  Are you sure this is what you want to check for?  This is not the same as determining whether an arbitrary expression is integer or real (or rational or complex).  Neither of `Pi`, `Sqrt[2]`, `2/3` are either of `Integer` or `Real` type, but they are all real numbers.

Comment: You need [`Alternatives`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Alternatives.html) rather than [`Or`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Or.html).  Either `x : (_Integer | _Real)` or `x_Integer | x_Real` will work.

Comment: Related to Szabolcs's note, you might want to just use `NumberQ[]`/`NumericQ[]` along with a test like `x_ /; Im[x] == 0`.

Comment: @Guess I was just getting around to that recommendation. :-)

Comment: Related, possible duplicate: [(84757)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/84757/121)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To match your literal request you need [`Alternatives`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Alternatives.html) rather than [`Or`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Or.html).
Either `x : (_Integer | _Real)` or `x_Integer | x_Real` will work.

Following what Szabolcs and "Guess who it is" wrote you might define a `realQ` like so:

```
realQ = NumericQ[#] && Im[#] == 0 &;

f[x_?realQ] := x^2

f /@ {1, Pi, 1.3, 2/3, x^2, 7.1 - 2.8 I}
```

> ```
> {1, π^2, 1.69, 4/9, f[x^2], f[7.1 - 2.8 I]}
> ```

Of note for those who are comfortable using undocumented functions:

```
Internal`RealValuedNumericQ /@ {1, Pi, 1.3, 2/3, x^2, 7.1 - 2.8 I}
```

> ```
> {True, True, True, True, False, False}
> ```

There is also `` Internal`RealValuedNumberQ `` which passes only *explicit* numbers:

```
Internal`RealValuedNumberQ /@ {1, Pi, 1.3, 2/3, x^2, 7.1 - 2.8 I}
```

> ```
> {True, False, True, True, False, False}
> ```

Comment: Thank you so much for the kind and elegant explanation!

Comment: @Smart You're welcome. :-)

Comment: Just a note: ``Internal`RealValuedNumberQ `` is consistent with the behavior of `NumberQ` which returns `False` when applied to `Pi`.

Comment: @rcollyer I intended to imply that; sorry if I failed.

Comment: Just making it explicit. Implications are often lost.

Comment: @Smart You're welcome; I'm glad I could help.

Answer (score 2):

I frequently write functions that take one or more arguments which I limit to those quantities that mathematicians call real numbers. In *Mathematica* that means any quantity satisfying `NumericQ` excepting complex numbers. To facilitate writing such functions, I define a pattern

```
validNum = Except[_Complex, _?NumericQ];
```

This pattern is used like so:

```
f[x : validNum] := x^2
```

#### Update

As Guesswhoitis points out the above is not fool-proof. A more robust version is

```
validNum = Except[z_ /; Head[N[z]] === Complex, _?NumericQ];
f /@ {1, 1/2, .5, Pi, 1 + I/2, 1. + .5 I, Sqrt[-1], (-1)^(2/3), E + I Pi}
```

> ```
> {1, 1/4, 0.25, Pi^2, f[1 + I/2], f[1. + 0.5*I], f[I], f[(-1)^(2/3)], f[E + I*Pi]}
> ```

Comment: How does it deal with `E + I Pi` or `(-1)^(2/3)`?

Comment: @Guesswhoitis. Not well, but I still find it useful.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard. You are right. I have fixed the error. I really must stop violating my  own principle of "never post code you have not tested".

Comment: @Guesswhoitis. Do you find my update more to your liking?

Comment: I guess the only thing that would trip it up now would be `1. + 0. I` and ilk, but it looks okay otherwise.

Comment: @Guesswhoitis. `f[1. + 0. I]` returns unevaluated, which is what I would expect and want. Why do you say `1. + 0. I` "trips it up"?

Comment: In that case, it's okay. :) I thought somebody might ask about imaginary parts that look but are not quite zero.

Comment: @m_goldberg  "never post code you have not tested" - Probably the first principle in computer science ever. And the most violated one ( even in 2021 ).