# Multiple replacements with single value/symbol

Tags: list-manipulation, replacement

I have a list $\{x,y,z,w,p\}$ and I want to replace $x,y,w$ by $q$. This works

```
{x,y,z,w,p}/.{x->q, y->q, p->q}
```

But is there a way to do this concisely? I tried the following, but doesn't work

```
{x,y,z,w,p}/.{(x || y || p) ->q}
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: closely related: [88301](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/88301/5478), [84757](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/84757/5478)

Comment: @Kuba Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
{x, y, z, w, p} /. Alternatives[x, y, p] -> q (* or *)
{x, y, z, w, p} /. Thread[{x, y, p} -> q]
```

> {q, q, z, w, q}

Answer (score 1):

```
list = {x, y, z, w, p};

rep = {x, y, p};

pos = Position[list, Alternatives @@ rep]
```

{{1}, {2}, {5}}

Using `MapAt` to to replace with single symbol

```
MapAt[q &, pos] @ list
```

{q, q, z, w, q}

Using `SubsetMap` to replace with different symbols (thanks, E. Chan-López)

```
SubsetMap[{q, r, s} &, list, pos]
```

{q, r, z, w, s}

With `ReplaceAt` (new in 13.1) we can easily impose additional
conditions

```
list = {x, 1, z, w, p};

ReplaceAt[_Symbol :> q, pos] @ list
```

{q, 1, z, w, q}