# Force only selected optional arguments

Tags: optional-arguments

Is there a way to force only selected values for function argument?
For example for this function:

```
g[x_, y_, a_: ("b" || "c")] := Print[x, y, a]
```

force `a` to only get either values `"b"` or `"c"`.

Comment: One way would be `g[x_, y_, a_] /; MemberQ[{"b", "c"}, a] := Print[x, y, a]`.

Comment: `ClearAll[g]; g[x_, y_, a : "b" | "c"] := Print[x, y, a]` ?

Comment: Thank you, @kglr and b.gates.you.know.what. Both answers worked. It's strange that I've tried kglr's answer multiple times before posting this question, but for some reason it failed to work properly.

Comment: At least closely related: [132037](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/132037/5478)

Answer (score 2):

Both answers of @kglr :

```
ClearAll[g]; g[x_, y_, a : "b" | "c"] := Print[x, y, a]
```

and @b.gates.you.know.what :

```
g[x_, y_, a_] /; MemberQ[{"b", "c"}, a] := Print[x, y, a]
```

worked.