# How to delete several cases?

Tags: list-manipulation

I want to delete the three cases

```
{"?", _}, {",", _}, {"XXX", _}
```

from the following list

```
{{"?", 13}, {"you", 11}, {"the", 8}, {",", 5}, {"of", 4}, {"to", 
  3}, {"did", 3}, {"are", 3}, {"XXX", 2}, {"with", 2}, {"When", 
  2}, {"were", 2}, {"see", 2}, {"Procuratorate", 2}, {"Your", 
  1}, {"your", 1}, {"XXXX.Your", 1}, {"XXXXCould", 1}, {"workers", 
  1}, {"Where", 1}, {"We", 1}, {"we", 1}, {"was", 1}, {"warrant", 
  1}, {"uh", 1}, {"Two", 1}, {"truth.", 1}, {"transportation", 
  1}, {"Today", 1}, {"thousand", 1}, {"that", 1}, {"tell", 
  1}, {"suspected", 1}, {"spell", 1}, {"sorry", 1}, {"some", 
  1}, {"shall", 1}, {"s", 1}, {"remember", 1}, {"please", 
  1}, {"People", 1}, {"passport", 1}, {"OK", 1}, {"number", 
  1}, {"nationality", 1}, {"name", 1}, {"leave", 1}, {"law", 
  1}, {"July", 1}, {"it", 1}, {"Is", 1}, {"interrogate", 1}, {"in", 
  1}, {"here", 1}, {"Guangzhou.", 1}, {"from", 1}, {"for", 
  1}, {"filed", 1}, {"facts", 1}, {"education", 1}, {"drug", 
  1}, {"Do", 1}, {"detention", 1}, {"detained", 1}, {"date", 
  1}, {"criminally", 1}, {"clear", 1}, {"case", 1}, {"birth", 
  1}, {"before", 1}, {"background", 1}, {"ascertain", 1}, {"As", 
  1}, {"arrested", 1}, {"arrest", 1}, {"approval.", 
  1}, {"application", 1}, {"and......", 1}, {"and", 1}, {"an", 
  1}, {"accordance", 1}, {"A00A0", 1}, {"82010816Sixteen", 
  1}, {"80XXX.Your", 1}, {"716When", 1}, {"198011Your", 1}, {"'", 1}}
```

I can delete one, but not three at once.

Comment: Have you tried using [`Alternatives`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Alternatives.html)?

Comment: yeah,thanks. I was trying || but it seemed to be |

Comment: closely related: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/84757/5478

Comment: In order to prevent it from being closed as a simple mistake I will mark it as a duplicate of a very closely related one. Let me know if you disagree.