# How to determine whether an expression can act as a "good" function?

Tags: programming, performance-tuning

It's not easy to see whether an expression can act as a "good" function.

A good function refers to an operater that transforms symbolic entities like `1+x^2` or numeric entities like `1+Sqrt[2]` into a new one.

(Remember that we only discuss the function,but not the function of function here.)

For example,
`Composition[#1^2&,InverseFunction[1/#1&]]` is a good function,
but `Composition[1[3],2[2]]` isn't.

So how to determine whether an expression can act as a "good" function in general cases?

Answer (score 4):

**In short: there's no reliable way, so don't bother.**  Leave it to the users of your function to pass correct arguments to it which are actually functions.  I think there was a question about this before, but I can't find it.

---

Why is this not possible?  There are many, many very different types of expressions in Mathematica that can act as functions, and each new version adds more.  They don't have a common attribute that identifies them as functions.  The only two ways to test would be:

- Try to check for each possibility, in which case you'll likely miss some, and won't be able to handle future additions
- Try to evaluate it with an argument, in which case undesirable thing might happen (slow functions, functions with side effects, etc.).  [Actually this is what `ValueQ` does internally for non-`OwnValue` cases.](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1474/12)

Examples of expressions that can act as functions:

- `DownValues`: `f[x_]:=x^2`
- `SubValues`: `a[_][_][x_]:=x^2`
- `Composition`
- `Function`
- `InterpolatingFunction`, `BooleanFunction`, `CompiledFunction`, `Association`s, etc.
- Operator forms such as `Map[f]`, `Apply[f]`, etc.
- probably many more that I can't think of right now