# How to apply or map a list of functions to a list of data?

Tags: list-manipulation

Say I have a group of functions:

```
f1[a_] := a * -1;
f2[a_] := a * 100;
f3[a_] := a / 10.0;
```

and some data in a list:

```
data := Range[1, 20];
```

I would like to apply this group of functions to the data: the first function applied to the first item of data, the second to the second, and so on. Because there are more data elements than there are functions, the first function is also applied to the fourth data element, and so on.

A simple work-round is this:

```
Flatten[{f1[#[[1]]], f2[#[[2]]], f3[#[[3]]]}  & /@ Partition[data, 3]]
```

giving

```
{-1, 200, 0.3, -4, 500, 0.6, -7, 800, 0.9, -10, 1100, 1.2, -13, 1400, 
  1.5, -16, 1700, 1.8}
```

but this isn't an ideal solution: the slots have been 'hard-wired', and it wouldn't be possible to modify the list of functions easily.

Is there a `Map`-related function that could do this elegantly? I've not been able to discover it yet.

(This is a toy example, of course!)

Comment: your current solution only goes up to 18, is that intentional?

Comment: Congrats on the 1024th question of this site!

Comment: Oh good, a nice round number: http://xkcd.com/1000/

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Here's how you can do it in a simple way:

```
functionMap[funcs_List, data_] := Module[{fn = RotateRight[funcs]}, 
    First[(fn = RotateLeft[fn])][#] & /@ data]
```

Use it as:

```
functionMap[{f1, f2, f3}, Range[20]]
(* {f1[1], f2[2], f3[3], f1[4], f2[5], f3[6], f1[7], f2[8], f3[9], f1[10],
    f2[11], f3[12], f1[13], f2[14], f3[15], f1[16], f2[17], f3[18], f1[19], f2[20]} *)
```

Comment: Oooo, clever. +1 (you know I like [that approach](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/1447/121).)

Comment: You could write it as a closure: `makeRotator[funcs_] := 
 Module[{fn = funcs}, First[(fn = RotateLeft[fn])][#] &]` then `makeRotator[{f1,f2,f3}] /@ Range[10]`.

Comment: Shorter/simpler: `{fn = funcs}` and `Last[(fn = RotateLeft[fn])]`

Answer (score 32):

Use [`PadRight`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/PadRight.html) with the cyclical padding setup:

```
funcs = {f1, f2, f3};
data = Range[1, 20];
MapThread[#1[#2] &, {PadRight[funcs, Length@data, funcs], data}]
```

or

```
MapThread[Compose, {PadRight[funcs, Length@data, funcs], data}]
```

> `{f1[1], f2[2], f3[3], f1[4], f2[5], f3[6], f1[7], f2[8], f3[9], f1[10], f2[11], f3[12], f1[13], f2[14], f3[15], f1[16], f2[17], f3[18], f1[19], f2[20]}`

Comment: You'll get a populist badge pretty soon :) Congrats in advance!

Comment: I wrote a solution myself before looking at the answers.  It was exactly this one, nearly character by character. :)

Comment: @Szabolcs: Great minds when meet... :) Thanks R.M, you should know that usually I use your method.

Answer (score 21):

```
MapIndexed[{f1, f2, f3}[[Mod[First@#2, 3, 1]]][#1] &, data]
```

does what you want (thanks to Sjoerd for pointing out a silly inefficiency).

Comment: This is more or less what I was thinking about too, but I wouldn't give the arguments to the functions first. In this way you're doing 3 times more calculations than necessary. Just put a [#1] after the `Part` and leave the function list alone.

Comment: @Sjoerd yes good point, also, this way it generalizes better. thanks

Answer (score 20):

Another approach

```
#1@#2 & @@@ 
  Partition[Riffle[Range[20], {f1, f2, f3}, {1, -1, 2}], 2]
```

Comparing with [Acl's solution](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/3861/52):

```
#1@#2 & @@@ 
  Partition[Riffle[Range[20], {f1, f2, f3}, {1, -1, 2}], 2] == 
 MapIndexed[{f1@#1, f2@#1, f3@#1}[[Mod[First@#2, 3, 1]]] &, data
```

==> True

Comment: nice one +1. Can save few key strokes with `#2@#1 & @@@ Partition[Riffle[Range[20], {f1, f2, f3}], 2]`:)

Answer (score 17):

Another approach using `Fold` in combination with `Sow`/`Reap`:

```
Reap[Fold[(Sow[#[[1]][#2]]; RotateLeft[#]) &, {f1, f2, f3}, data];][[2, 1]]
```

Answer (score 17):

Another approach is to use `Outer`, as follows

```
Flatten@Outer[#1[#2]&, {f1, f2, f3}, Range[1,5]]
(*
{f1[1], f1[2], f1[3], f1[4], f1[5], 
 f2[1], f2[2], f2[3], f2[4], f2[5],
 f3[1], f3[2], f3[3], f3[4], f3[5]}
*)
```

---

Unfortunately, `Outer` causes problems if the data points are vectors, for instance

```
Flatten@Outer[#1[#2] &, {f1, f2, f3}, {#, #} & /@ Range[1, 3]]
```

produces

```
{f1[1], f1[1], f1[2], f1[2], f1[3], f1[3], 
 f2[1], f2[1], f2[2], f2[2], f2[3], f2[3], 
 f3[1], f3[1], f3[2], f3[2], f3[3], f3[3]}
```

To work around this, you need to use the 3$^\text{rd}$ and subsequent parameters of `Outer` which are level specifications:

```
Outer[#1[#2] &, {f1, f2, f3}, {#, #} & /@ Range[1, 3], Infinity, 1] //
  Flatten
(*
{f1[{1, 1}], f1[{2, 2}], f1[{3, 3}], 
 f2[{1, 1}], f2[{2, 2}], f2[{3, 3}], 
 f3[{1, 1}], f3[{2, 2}], f3[{3, 3}]}
*)
```

Or, if you prefer

```
Outer[#1 @@ #2 &, {f1, f2, f3}, {#, #} & /@ Range[1, 3], Infinity, 1] //
  Flatten
(*
{f1[1, 1], f1[2, 2], f1[3, 3], 
 f2[1, 1], f2[2, 2], f2[3, 3], 
 f3[1, 1], f3[2, 2], f3[3, 3]}
*)
```

Answer (score 8):

Would the following qualify as elegant or not?

```
mapFunctions[funcs_, list_] := Module[{r = list, u},
  applyFunc[f_, l_, i_, t_] := 
   MapAt[f, l, Table[{u}, {u, i, Length[l], t}]];
  Do[r = applyFunc[funcs[[u]], r, u, Length[funcs]],
   {u, Length[funcs]}];
  Return[r];
  ]
```

which gives:

```
In[9]:= MapFunctions[{f1, f2, f3}, data]

Out[9]= {f1[1], f2[2], f3[3], f1[4], f2[5], f3[6], f1[7], f2[8], 
 f3[9], f1[10], f2[11], f3[12], f1[13], f2[14], f3[15], f1[16], 
 f2[17], f3[18], f1[19], f2[20]}
```

Comment: Well, it has a `Do`. What would you say? ;-)

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries but it has no `Goto`, I swear!

Answer (score 1):

Using `Query`

```
f1[a_] := a * -1;
f2[a_] := a * 100;
f3[a_] := a / 10.0;

data = Partition[Range @ 18, 3]

Query[All, {1 -> f1, 2 -> f2, 3 -> f3}] @ data
```

{{-1, 200, 0.3}, {-4, 500, 0.6}, {-7, 800, 0.9}, {-10, 1100,
1.2}, {-13, 1400, 1.5}, {-16, 1700, 1.8}}

In a simple case like this we don't need the `f` - definitions:

```
Query[All, Thread[{1, 2, 3} -> {# * -1 &, # * 100 &, # / 10. &}]] @ data
```

This gives, of course, the same result.