# How to generate patterns by a list of integers

Tags: list-manipulation, pattern-matching

I have a list of integers `{3,4,2,2}`.

This list will give patterns `{x_,_,y_,y_,_,_,z_,z_,w_,w_,x_}` and `{0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1}`.

Notice that I want to assign successive `0,1` with the same symbol.

How to make this?

*edit

Compare the patterns

```
{x_,_,y_,y_,_,_,z_,z_,w_,w_,x_}
{0, 0, 0,1, 1,1, 1,0,  0,1, 1 }
{1, _, 2,2, _,_, 3,3,  4,4, 1 }
```

Suppose I have symbols `{x_,y_,z_,w_}` (you may use `{a_,b_,c_,d_,...}`).

To transform `lst={3,4,2,2}` to `{x_,_,y_,y_,_,_,z_,z_,w_,w_,x_}`,
begin with `{x_,_,_,_,_,_,_,_,_,_,_}`.

Then put `y_` at positions `lst[[1]]` and `lst[[1]]+1`.

Then put `z_` at positions `lst[[1]]+lst[[2]]` and `lst[[1]]+lst[[2]]+1`.

Then put `w_` at positions `lst[[1]]+lst[[2]]+lst[[3]]` and `lst[[1]]+lst[[2]]+lst[[3]]+1`.

And finally put `x_` at the last position.

Comment: observe that when `0` is next to `1`, assign them with the same symbol. If `0` is next to `0` (or `1` is next to `1`), assign with `_`.

Comment: Please tell us how you intend to use the pattern `{x_,_,y_,y_,_,_,z_,z_,w_,w_,x_}`? Also, how would you extend the symbol list it there were, say, 7 control integers rather than 4?

Comment: praaeew, thanks for the update, which I finally understand.  Would you please consider splitting that into a separate question?  I think it deserves to be addressed on its own.

Comment: Also, how should a list `{3, 4, 1, 2}` be handled?

Comment: The integer in the list must be >=2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like others I cannot follow the `{x_,_,y_,y_,_,_,z_,z_,w_,w_,x_}` part but for the integer sequence this problem is related to: [How to apply or map a list of functions to a list of data?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3858/121)

Any of those solutions should be adaptable but for this particular application I like TomD's method the best.  It is both concise and very fast.

```
f[pat : {__Integer}, rep_List] /; Min[pat] > 0 :=
  Join @@ ConstantArray @@@ Partition[Riffle[pat, rep, {1, -1, 2}], 2]

f[{3, 4, 2, 2}, {0, 1}]
```

> ```
> {0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1}
> ```

---

Here is one that is a bit shorter and faster still:

```
f2[p : {__Integer}, r_List] /; Min[p] > 0 :=
  Inner[ConstantArray, PadRight[r, Length @ p, r], p, Join]

f2[{3, 4, 2, 2}, {0, 1}]
```

> ```
> {0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1}
> ```

---

In response to your updated question you could use this:

```
lst = {3, 4, 2, 2};

ReplacePart[
 ConstantArray[_, Tr@lst],
 Prepend[
  {{#}, {# + 1}} -> (Pattern[#, _] &@Unique[]) & /@ Accumulate@lst,
  {{1}, {-1}} -> x_
 ]
]
```

> ```
> {x_, _, $1_, $1_, _, _, $2_, $2_, $3_, $3_, x_}
> ```

This generates as many `Unique` symbols as required to fill out the list.

I still think this is distinct from the integer sequence result and should be split to a separate question.  I also echo m_goldberg's question: "How do you intend to use the pattern?" as there may be another approach.

Comment: Actually, the problem is there are two copies of `{1,2,3,4,5,6,7}` named group `0` and group `1`, and I want to arrange them as a cycle in which there are double digit 4 places. The list `{3,4,4,3}` separates group `0` and `1` by `{0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1}`. A valid arrangement is such as `{1, 5, 2,2, 6,7, 3,3, 6,7, 4,4, 5, 1}`. (sorry for asking `{3,4,2,2}` that is not compatible with real problem.)

Comment: @praaeew I'm once again having trouble understanding you (we probably have a different way of thinking).  If the update to my answer does not solve your problem, *please* post a new question with further clarification of the pattern you seek.

Answer (score 2):

One part of the question is easy -- constructing a sequence of ones and zeros according to a pattern given by a control list of integers:

```
binaryPattern[controlList : {_Integer ..}] := 
   Flatten@MapIndexed[
      If[EvenQ @@ #2, ConstantArray[1, #1], ConstantArray[0, #1]] &, controlList]

binaryPattern[{3, 4, 2, 2}]
```

> {0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1}

```
binaryPattern[{1, 2, 3, 4}]
```

> {0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1}

About the other part, I haven't a clue of what the OP has in mind.

#### Edit

Slightly modifying the function Mr. Wizard defined in his comment to this answer, I present a function that produces sequences of digits from any base from two to ten. I confess I can think of no use case for this extended version.

```
nAryPattern[controlList : {__Integer}, base_Integer: 2] /; 11 > base > 1 := 
   Join @@ MapIndexed[ConstantArray[Mod[#2[[1]] - 1, base], #] & controlList]  

Table[nAryPattern[Range[5], base], {base, 2, 5}]
```

> {
> {0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
> {0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1},
> {0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
> {0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4}
> }

Comment: I propose this extension: `binaryPattern[ctrl : {__Integer}, m_Integer: 2] :=
 Join @@ MapIndexed[Mod[#2[[1]] - 1, m] ~ConstantArray~ # &, ctrl]`  -- the second (optional) argument determines the length of the repeating cycle.  This is also a bit faster and more concise.