# Plotting multiple parametric functions with different intervals

Tags: plotting

I want to make a parametric plot like this:

```
ParametricPlot[{{2 t, -10 t^2}, {t, 2 t}}, {t, 0, 2}]
```

I have tried the following but it doesn't work:

```
ParametricPlot[{{2 t, -10 t^2}, {t, 2 t}}, {{t, 0, 2}, {t, 4, 7}}]
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`ConditionalExpression[]` works nicely:

```
ParametricPlot[{ConditionalExpression[{2 t, -10 t^2}, 0 <= t <= 2], 
                ConditionalExpression[{t, 2 t}, 4 <= t <= 7]}, {t, 0, 7}, 
               AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio]
```

[image: split plots]

Comment: J.M. are you back? :-D

Comment: Well, back... ish.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, appreciate it!

Comment: @user1626227 This is a fine answer, and perhaps the best one you are going to get, but as a rule I recommend that you leave more time before you Accept an answer.  I usually wait 24 hours so that people in all time zones have a chance to read the question and respond if they choose, before the question appears concluded.

Answer (score 4):

Without conditional constructs, just building a list of your functions and limits

```
intervals = {{{2 t, -10  t^2}, {0, 2}}, {{t, 2 t}, {4, 7}}};
Show[ParametricPlot[#[[1]], Evaluate@{t, Sequence @@ #[[2]]}] & /@  intervals,
     PlotRange -> Automatic, AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

**Edit**
You may prefer to use `\[FormalT]` instead of simply `t` for protection against possible definitions of `t` elsewhere.

**Edit 2**

A more featured implementation, taking the color switching from @Mr's answer and forcing it to cycle so allowing to take any number of curves as argument:

```
f[{var_, l1_}] := Module[{style = ColorData[1] /@ Range@5},
  Show[ParametricPlot[#[[1]], Evaluate@{var, Sequence @@ #[[2]]}] & /@ l1 /.
       x_Line :> {First@(style = RotateRight[style]), x}, 
       PlotRange -> Automatic, AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio]]
```

Usage:

```
l = {\[FormalT],Array[{{RandomInteger[10]\[FormalT],RandomInteger[{-10,10}]   
                    \[FormalT]^RandomReal[2]},RandomInteger[10,2]}&,10]};
f[l]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: If `t` is defined this fails.  I think you should add a `Block` or at least a warning.  (+1 nevertheless)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Usually I use `\[FormalT]`, but I rather prefer to keep the code clean here

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Updated with the warning

Comment: I would have used `MapThread[]` instead of `Map[]` myself...

Comment: @J.M. Why? I wanted the function and its associated interval clustered in one list ...

Comment: Oh, you had the thing transposed. In that case... `ParametricPlot[#1, Prepend[#2, t] // Evaluate] & @@@ {{{2 t, -10 t^2}, {0, 2}}, {{t, 2 t}, {4, 7}}}`.

Answer (score 3):

For version 7 users without `ConditionalExpression` there is `Piecewise`:

```
ParametricPlot[
  Piecewise[{{{2 t, -10 t^2}, 0 <= t <= 2}, {{t, 2 t}, 4 <= t <= 7}}], {t, 0, 7},
  AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio
]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

To get separate styles requires [additional work](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1128/121):

```
ParametricPlot[
 pwSplit @ Piecewise[{{{2 t, -10 t^2}, 0 <= t <= 2}, {{t, 2 t}, 4 <= t <= 7}}],
 {t, 0, 7},
 AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio,
 PlotStyle -> {Red, Blue},
 Evaluated -> True
]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

`pwSplit` code from [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/1129/121).  Or:

```
Module[{style = {Red, Blue}, i = 1},
 ParametricPlot[
   Piecewise[{{{2 t, -10 t^2}, 0 <= t <= 2}, {{t, 2 t}, 4 <= t <= 7}}], {t, 0, 7},
   AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio
 ] /. x_Line :> {style[[i++]], x}
]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: +1 How about something like `x_Line :> {First@(style = RotateRight[style]), x}` in your last piece of code?

Comment: @belisarius that's a good suggestion if one wishes for cyclic behavior.  R.M [would be pleased.](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/3876/121)  You could also use `Mod`.