# How to replace an element in a list with an element in another list with matching indices?

Tags: list-manipulation, replacement, rule

I have a list like this `l = {1 + 2*s, 2 + 3*s, 4 + 1*s}`, and I have calculated `s = {1, 2, 3}`. I need to replace `s` in `l` so that `l = {1 + 2*1, 2 + 3*2, 4 + 1*3}`. Is it possible to do that with `ReplacAll` (`/.`) and `Rule`?

Comment: Did one of the answers below answer your question? If so, please accept it!

Comment: Somewhat related: [(3858)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3858/121)

Comment: @Developer2000, is the idea of your question to avoid other structural constructs except `/.`?

Answer (score 10):

Here's some ways. Using:

```
l = {1+2*s,2+3*s,4+1*s};
slist = {1, 2, 3};
```

The answer closest to what you asked is

```
{1 + 2*s, 2 + 3*s, 4 + 1*s} /. s -> slist // Diagonal
```

However, that does `3^2 - 3` too many calculations, so here's some more ways.

```
Module[{i = 1}, l /. s :> slist[[i++]]]
MapThread[#1 /. s -> #2 &, {l, slist}]
MapThread[ReplaceAll, {l, Thread[s -> slist]}]
ReplaceAll @@@ Transpose[{l, Thread[s -> slist]}]
Map[First@#1 /. s -> Last@#1 &, Transpose@{l, slist}]
MapIndexed[#1 /. s -> slist[[First@#2]] &, l]
```

If `s` is always going to be the list `{1, 2, 3, ...}`, then:

```
MapIndexed[#1 /. s -> First@#2 &, l]
```

Comment: Hey, you even got the one with `Diagonal`!  Nice work.  You could avoid the extraneous computations I believe by using `Diagonal[l /. List /@ Thread[s -> slist]]` though I admit that is sadly not so pretty.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard. And I feel like I'm still missing some that are actually different in nature to those above (practically all of these rely on the same idea). My favorite is the `PostIncrement` one, though; one of my favorite slick tricks (that I learned here somewhere along the way).

Comment: If I think if anything else that's not contrived I'll post it.

Answer (score 8):

```
list={1+2*s,2+3*s,4+1*s};

sValues={1,2,3};
```

Using `HoldForm` to see the intermediate step

```
Inner[HoldForm[#1 /. s -> #2]&, list, sValues, List]

(*  {1+2 s/. s->1,2+3 s/. s->2,4+s/. s->3}  *)

%//ReleaseHold

(*  {3,8,7}  *)
```

Without the intermediate step

```
Inner[#1 /. s -> #2 &, list, sValues, List]

(*  {3,8,7}  *)
```

Comment: I really don't get to use `Inner` enough. Love the use of `Inner` for this problem.

Answer (score 4):

```
l = {1 + 2*s, 2 + 3*s, 4 + 1*s};
slist = {1, 2, 3};
```

#### SubsetMap

```
SubsetMap[slist &, Position[l, s]] @ l
```

> ```
> {3, 8, 7}
> ```

#### ReplaceAll

```
l /. s :> Last[slist = RotateLeft[slist]]
```

> ```
> {3, 8, 7}
> ```

Comment: +1 - a very useful (undocumented?) use of `SubsetMap `

Answer (score 3):

```
a = {1 + 2*s, 2 + 3*s, 4 + 1*s};
b = {1, 2, 3};

ReplacePart[i_ :> (a[[i]] /. s :> b[[i]])] @ list
```

{3, 8, 7}

Answer (score 2):

```
{#1[[1]] /. s -> #2[[1]], #1[[2]] /. s -> #2[[2]], #1[[3]] /. 
    s -> #2[[3]]} &[{1+2*s,2+3*s,4+1*s}, {1,2,3}]
```

Comment: `Table[(#1[[i]] /. s -> #2[[i]]), {i, 3}] &[l,{1,2,3}]`

Comment: `ReplacePart[l, Thread[Position[l, s] -> {1,2,3}]`

Answer (score 1):

An alternative is to use `MapAt` and `Diagonal` as follows:

```
a = {1 + 2*s, 2 + 3*s, 4 + 1*s};
b = {1, 2, 3};

Diagonal@MapAt[b &, a, Position[a, s]]

(*{3, 8, 7}*)
```