# Nest list with two functions

Tags: list-manipulation, core-language

Is it possible to use the NestList command with two functions, one at every even step and apply the other at every odd step.  If this is possible could someone share an example ?

Answer (score 18):

**Update:**

I think that the cleanest way is to use `ComposeList` (as suggested by kglr),
but with `PadRight` to generate `{f,g,f,g,f,...}` sequence:

```
ComposeList[PadRight[{}, 5, {f, g}], x]
```

> {x, f[x], g[f[x]], f[g[f[x]]], g[f[g[f[x]]]], f[g[f[g[f[x]]]]]}

It can be easily generalized to a larger number of functions:

```
ComposeList[PadRight[{}, 5, {f, g, h}], x]
```

> {x, f[x], g[f[x]], h[g[f[x]]], f[h[g[f[x]]]], g[f[h[g[f[x]]]]]}

**Original answer:**

Here is one possibilty using `FoldList`:

```
FoldList[If[OddQ[#2], f[#], g[#]]&, x, Range[4]]
```

> {x, f[x], g[f[x]], f[g[f[x]]], g[f[g[f[x]]]]}

Answer (score 15):

I would probably use `NestList` in the semi-imperative style shown in the [answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/147058/142) of [kglr](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/125/kglr)... but here is a way in functional style:

```
NestList[Apply[{#2@#, #3, #2} &], {x, f, g}, 5][[All, 1]]

(* {x, f[x], g[f[x]], f[g[f[x]]], g[f[g[f[x]]]], f[g[f[g[f[x]]]]]} *)
```

Comment: I would consider it as "wierdo style" ;) but +1

Answer (score 12):

**Update:** Another variation on `ComposeList`:

```
ComposeList[PadRight[##, "Periodic"], x] &[{f, g}, 5]
```

> {x, f[x], g[f[x]], f[g[f[x]]], g[f[g[f[x]]]], f[g[f[g[f[x]]]]]}

```
ComposeList[PadRight[##, "Periodic"], x] &[{f, g, h}, 5]
```

> {x, f[x], g[f[x]], h[g[f[x]]], f[h[g[f[x]]]], g[f[h[g[f[x]]]]]}

Similarly, on `FoldList`:

```
FoldList[#2@# &, x, PadRight[##, "Periodic"]] &[{f, g, h}, 5]
```

> {x, f[x], g[f[x]], h[g[f[x]]], f[h[g[f[x]]]], g[f[h[g[f[x]]]]]}

And a variation on @WReach's approach:

```
foo = {{f, g }[[#2]]@#, 3 - #2} & @@ # &;
NestList[foo, {x, 1}, 5][[All, 1]]
```

> {x, f[x], g[f[x]], f[g[f[x]]], g[f[g[f[x]]]], f[g[f[g[f[x]]]]]}

**Original post:**

Using `NestList`

```
i = 1; NestList[{f1, f2}[[Mod[i++, 2, 1]]][#] &, x, 5]
```

> {x, f1[x], f2[f1[x]], f1[f2[f1[x]]], f2[f1[f2[f1[x]]]], f1[f2[f1[f2[f1[x]]]]]}

We get the same result using `ComposeList`:

```
ComposeList[{f1, f2}[[Mod[Range[5], 2, 1]]], x]
```

or `FoldList` in alternative ways:

```
FoldList[{f1, f2}[[Mod[#2, 2, 1]]][#] &, x, Range@5]
FoldList[#2@# &, x, {f1, f2}[[Mod[Range[5], 2, 1]]]]
```

Answer (score 12):

We can apply R.M's method from [How to apply or map a list of functions to a list of data?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3858/121)

I'll show an example with three functions to demonstrate generality; two work just as well.

```
fns = {f, g, h};

NestList[Last[fns = RotateLeft[fns]][#] &, x, 5]
```

> ```
> {x, f[x], g[f[x]], h[g[f[x]]], f[h[g[f[x]]]], g[f[h[g[f[x]]]]]}
> ```

Comment: @MrWizard, same style solution: `tmp = h; NestList[(tmp = tmp /. {f -> g, g -> h, h -> f})[#] &, x, 5]`

Answer (score 4):

```
FoldList[#2[#1] &, x, Riffle[Table[f, 3], g]]

(* {x, f[x], g[f[x]], f[g[f[x]]], g[f[g[f[x]]]], f[g[f[g[f[x]]]]]} *)
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's my take using a counter:

```
Block[{i = 1}, NestList[Unevaluated[{f, g}[[ Mod[i++, 2, 1] ]] ], x, 5]]
```

> ```
> {x, f[x], g[f[x]], f[g[f[x]]], g[f[g[f[x]]]], f[g[f[g[f[x]]]]]}
> ```

A golfier variation of the same (but vulnerable to existing definitions of `f[g]`):

```
Block[{i = 0}, NestList[Unevaluated[f[g][[i++~Mod~2]]], x, 5]]
```

Answer (score 1):

In:

```
nest[f_, g_, x_, n_] /; EvenQ[n] := Nest[g@*f, x, n/2]
nest[f_, g_, x_, n_] /; OddQ[n] := f@Nest[g@*f, x, (n - 1)/2]
nestlist[f_, g_, x_, n_] := Table[nest[f, g, x, i], {i, 0, n}]
nestlist[f, g, x, 5]
```

Out:

```
{x, f[x], g[f[x]], f[g[f[x]]], g[f[g[f[x]]]], f[g[f[g[f[x]]]]]}
```

Comment: This solution works but not exactly like `NestList`. Because `NestList` calculates `f[x]` only once, and then uses that value in the next iterations, while this solution will recalculate `f[x]` on each step. This can be important if `f` has side effects i.e. `f[x_] := (Print["Calculating f[", x, "]"]; ff[x])`.

Comment: @Shadowray Thanks! It's a surprise. I didn't know NestList calculate f[x] only once. And I assumed that f and g are purely functional functions. I made too many assumptions in this case.

Answer (score 1):

`NetList` is not really the right choice for this, but you can use `Nest` with `Sow` and `Reap` the intermediate results.  E.g.,

```
ClearAll[f, g]
Last@Last@Reap@Nest[Sow@f[Sow@g[#]] &, x0, 3]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Nest[If[Head@# === g, f, g]@# &, x, 6]
```

This is a bad solution. Now I changed it.

```
f[g_, f_, n_] := 
    Module[{g1, f1}, 
    NestList[If[Head@# === g1, f1, g1]@# &, x, n] /. {g1 -> g, f1 -> f}]
```

To avoid recalculating f[x] at each step:

```
f[g_, f_, n_] := 
    NestList[If[Head@# === Hold[g], Hold[f], Hold[g]]@ReleaseHold@# &, x, n + 1][[2 ;;, 1]]
```

Comment: @Shadowray Thank you for pointing out my mistake

Comment: No problem. Note that your new solution has the same specifics as the one by UnchartedWorks. I.e. it will recalculate f[x] at each step.

Comment: @Shadowray Thank you again. I have changed my answer.