# Convert head Times to List

Tags: list-manipulation

I can convert an expression with the head of Times,for example, `12*12.5*13*13.5*14*14.5` to `{12, 12.5, 13, 13.5, 14, 14.5}` by using the code below：

```
ReleaseHold[HoldForm[12*12.5*13*13.5*14*14.5] /. Times -> List]
```

I have a list which contains a lot of such expressions,here is an example:

```
listSample={12*12.5*13*13.5*14*14.5, 12*12.5*13*13.5*14*14.5,12*12.5*13*13.5*14*14.5, 12*12.5*13*13.5*14*14.5,12*12.5*13*13.5*14*14.5,12*12.5*13*13.5*14*14.5}
```

I still want to convert all the heads `Times` to `List`,but I failed when tried to Map `HoldForm` to each listItem,because it alway evaluates first.
Here is my code:

```
ReleaseHold[HoldForm[#] /. Times -> List]&/@listSample
```

I want to get this result:

> {{12, 12.5, 13, 13.5, 14, 14.5},{12, 12.5, 13, 13.5, 14, 14.5},{12, 12.5, 13, 13.5, 14, 14.5},{12, 12.5, 13, 13.5, 14, 14.5},{12, 12.5, 13, 13.5, 14, 14.5},{12, 12.5, 13, 13.5, 14, 14.5}}

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `listSample` containing the lists of multiplications must at all times remain wrapped in something that prevents it from being evaluated. So even the mere input line with which you define `listSample` is not going to work.

When you `Map` a function onto `listSample`, the latter isn't wrapped the way it should be, so it gets evaluated. You can't use `Map` directly on things that you would like to keep unevaluated. Fortunately, you don't need `Map` in this case since you only want to replace `Times` by `List`.

So I'd suggest the following definition which makes the process re-useable:

```
SetAttributes[removeTimes, HoldAll]; 
removeTimes[list_] := ReleaseHold[Hold[list] /. Times -> List]
```

Now you can take your example list literally and wrap it in the above function:

```
removeTimes[
 {12*12.5*13*13.5*14*14.5, 12*12.5*13*13.5*14*14.5, 
  12*12.5*13*13.5*14*14.5, 12*12.5*13*13.5*14*14.5, 
  12*12.5*13*13.5*14*14.5, 12*12.5*13*13.5*14*14.5}]
```

> `{{12, 12.5, 13, 13.5, 14, 14.5}, {12, 12.5, 13, 13.5, 14, 14.5}, {12, 
>         12.5, 13, 13.5, 14, 14.5}, {12, 12.5, 13, 13.5, 14, 14.5}, {12, 
>         12.5, 13, 13.5, 14, 14.5}, {12, 12.5, 13, 13.5, 14, 14.5}}`

Comment: Very useful, for instance if one does copy+paste of a row with numbers from Excel into Mathematica.

Answer (score 9):

```
data=HoldForm@{12*12.5*13*13.5*14*14.5, 12*12.5*13*13.5*14*14.5,12*12.5*13*13.5*14*14.5, 12*12.5*13*13.5*14*14.5, 2*12.5*13*13.5*14*14.5, 12*12.5*13*13.5*14*14.5};
data/.Times->List // ReleaseHold
```

gives

```
{{12, 12.5`, 13, 13.5`, 14, 14.5`}, {12, 12.5`, 13, 13.5`, 14, 14.5`}, 
 {12, 12.5`, 13, 13.5`, 14, 14.5`}, {12, 12.5`, 13, 13.5`,14, 14.5`},
 {12, 12.5`, 13, 13.5`, 14, 14.5`}, {12, 12.5`, 13, 13.5`, 14, 14.5`}}
```

EDIT: An alternative:

```
timesToList = Function[{list}, Unevaluated[list] /. Times -> List, HoldAll]
timesToList[{12*12.5*13*13.5*14*14.5, 12*12.5*13*13.5*14*14.5}]
(* ==> {{12, 12.5, 13, 13.5, 14, 14.5}, {12, 12.5, 13, 13.5, 14, 14.5}} *)
```

Comment: wow,your code is concise,+1

Answer (score 8):

The value assigned `listSample` must be held unevaluated by some means or manipulation is not possible (as there is no `Times` present).  There are several options for this:

1. `Hold`
2. `Unevaluated`
3. `SetDelayed` (`:=`)

Of these `SetDelayed` is the most concise, so I will use that:

```
listSample := {12*12.5*13*13.5*14*14.5, 12*12.5*13*13.5*14*14.5};
```

Normally this is fully evaluated as soon as you call `listSample`:

```
listSample
```

> ```
> {5.34398*10^6, 5.34398*10^6}
> ```

It is nevertheless stored internally in the unevaluated form.  Because of this we can use `Block` to temporarily change the meaning of `Times` to `List` while this evaluation is taking place:

```
Block[{Times = List}, listSample]
```

> ```
> {{12, 12.5, 13, 13.5, 14, 14.5},
>  {12, 12.5, 13, 13.5, 14, 14.5}}
> ```

You could also access the unevaluated data with `OwnValues` or with my [step evaluation function](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/1447/121) which I wrote for this purpose.

```
step[listSample] /. Times -> List // ReleaseHold
```

This approach would be useful if you needed to do a more complex replacement than you could do with `Block`, as would `Hold` or `Unevaluated`.

---

Also consider this:

```
Unevaluated[12*12.5*13*13.5*14*14.5] /. Times -> List
```

> ```
> {12, 12.5, 13, 13.5, 14, 14.5}
> ```

Notice that no `ReleaseHold` is needed in this case as `Unevaluated` momentarily holds its argument, unlike `Hold` which does so until released.

Comment: When should we use `Unevaluated` as opposed to `Hold`?

Comment: @Michael specific to this application, or generally?

Comment: Generally.  I know that `Unevaluated` dissolves after we pass it through a function, but are there other considerations to keep in mind?

Comment: I am just wondering if you have a rule of thumb to recognize when to use `Hold` as opposed to `Unevaluated`.

Comment: @Michael basically what you just outlined: use `Unevaluated` when you want it to "dissolve" after one use, otherwise use `Hold`.

Comment: Btw, I very much like the `SetDelayed` idea!

Answer (score 4):

Given the way you defined `listSample`, Mathematica evaluates the RHS before setting the value.  To understand why this is the case, you may want to read the documentation for the [standard evaluation procedure](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/TheStandardEvaluationProcedure.html).

```
In[21]:= listSample
Out[21]= {5.34398*10^6,5.34398*10^6,5.34398*10^6,5.34398*10^6,5.34398*10^6,5.34398*10^6}
```

Before we can manipulate this list of products, we need to make sure that the RHS is not evaluated.  Strictly speaking, `Hold` as opposed to `HoldForm` suffices as do not need pretty-printing.

```
In[22]:= listSample2=Hold@{12*12.5*13*13.5*14*14.5,12*12.5*13*13.5*14*14.5,12*12.5*13*13.5*14*14.5,12*12.5*13*13.5*14*14.5,12*12.5*13*13.5*14*14.5,12*12.5*13*13.5*14*14.5}
Out[22]= Hold[{12 12.5 13 13.5 14 14.5,12 12.5 13 13.5 14 14.5,12 12.5 13 13.5 14 14.5,12 12.5 13 13.5 14 14.5,12 12.5 13 13.5 14 14.5,12 12.5 13 13.5 14 14.5}]
```

Before I do any sort of manipulation, I find it useful to look at its `FullForm`:

```
In[23]:= FullForm@listSample2
Out[23]//FullForm= Hold[List[Times[12,12.5`,13,13.5`,14,14.5`],Times[12,12.5`,13,13.5`,14,14.5`],Times[12,12.5`,13,13.5`,14,14.5`],Times[12,12.5`,13,13.5`,14,14.5`],Times[12,12.5`,13,13.5`,14,14.5`],Times[12,12.5`,13,13.5`,14,14.5`]]]
```

Another useful representation is `TreeForm`:

```
In[24]:= TreeForm@listSample2
```

[image: TreeForm of listSample2]

Either way, we see that the heads `Times` we want to replace are all at level `{2}`.  `Apply` is the built-in function which replaces head, so we can use

```
In[25]:= ReleaseHold@Apply[List,listSample2,{2}]
Out[25]= {{12,12.5,13,13.5,14,14.5},{12,12.5,13,13.5,14,14.5},{12,12.5,13,13.5,14,14.5},{12,12.5,13,13.5,14,14.5},{12,12.5,13,13.5,14,14.5},{12,12.5,13,13.5,14,14.5}}
```