# Extract function arguments

Tags: list-manipulation, functions

Is there a way to extract the arguments of a function? Consider the following example:

I have this sum

```
g[1] + g[2] + g[3] + g[1]*g[3] + 3*g[1]*g[2] + 6*g[1]*g[2]*g[3]
```

Now, what I want to do is exctract the function arguments and apply them to another function `func` which takes the arguments as a list.

```
func[{1}] + func[{2}] + func[{3}] + func[{1, 3}] + 3*func[{1, 2}] + 6*func[{1, 2, 3}]
```

I know there is `Extract[g[1]*g[3], Position[g[1]*g[3], _Integer]]` but that does not work if I have a multiplicative constant.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The pattern for a direct replacement proves to be a bit tricky:

```
start = g[1] + g[2] + g[3] + g[1]*g[3] + 3*g[1]*g[2] + 6*g[1]*g[2]*g[3];

start /. y__g z_g | y__g x_. :> x func[Join @@ List @@@ {y, z}]
```

> ```
> func[{1}] + func[{2}] + func[{3}] + 3 func[{1, 2}] + func[{1, 3}] + 6 func[{1, 2, 3}]
> ```

If order doesn't matter, and arguably it shouldn't with `Times` you could use:

```
start //. g[x__] g[y__] :> g[x, y] /. g[x__] :> func[{x}]
```

> ```
> func[{1}] + func[{2}] + func[{3}] + 3 func[{1, 2}] + func[{1, 3}] + 6 func[{3, 1, 2}]
> ```

---

The OP asked how to extract just the arguments of `g` and do so preserving the order of the input.  This requires wrapping the expression in `Hold` (or similar) before it is evaluated, to prevent the automatic sorting of `Plus`.  I shall use a variation of kguler's cleaner patten, and `Cases` since we want only parts of the expression and not the entire thing transformed.  I shall scan at *level 2* (rather than the default *level 1*) to bypass the additional Head.

```
start2 = Hold[g[1] + g[2] + g[3] + g[1]*g[3] + 3*g[1]*g[2] + 6*g[1]*g[2]*g[3]]

Cases[start2, (x___ : 1) p__g :> First /@ {p}, {2}]
```

> ```
> {{1}, {2}, {3}, {1, 3}, {1, 2}, {1, 2, 3}}
> ```

Let me take this opportunity to show an unusual but potentially useful method I also used for [Convert head Times to List](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/7842/121).  You can hold your expression unevaluated by using `SetDelayed`, but normally it is fully evaluated when it is called.  (This has the advantage of letting you use the expression elsewhere without additional effort such as `ReleaseHold`.)  To get around that when doing the extraction you can `Block` the functions that you do not want to evaluate during the call.  Example:

```
start3 := g[1] + g[2] + g[3] + g[1]*g[3] + 3*g[1]*g[2] + 6*g[1]*g[2]*g[3]

Block[{Plus},
  Cases[start3, (x___ : 1) p__g :> First /@ {p}]
]
```

> ```
> {{1}, {2}, {3}, {1, 3}, {1, 2}, {1, 2, 3}}
> ```

Alternatively, you could use [my `step` evaluator function](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/1447/121) to get the unevaluated expression wrapped in `HoldForm`, then use *level 2* again:

```
Cases[step @ start3, (x___ : 1) p__g :> First /@ {p}, {2}]
```

> ```
> {{1}, {2}, {3}, {1, 3}, {1, 2}, {1, 2, 3}}
> ```

Comment: Wizard! Thanks, the first solution really helps me. Do u maybe know how to get just the arguments in a list: just `{{1},{2},{3},{1,2},{1,3},{1,2,3}}` like in the example?

Comment: @rainer I don't know why you say "like in the example" as your example is clearly the form that I show in my answer.  If however you want the argument-only list you could do:  `Cases[start, (x___ : 1) p__g :> First /@ {p}]` (based on kguler's answer).  Note that the output is not in the same order that you show because the terms are automatically sorted by `Plus` before `Cases` even sees them.  If that is a problem you will need to define `start` using `Hold`.  Ask if you need help.

Comment: thank you. yes just the argument-only list, but I need it to be in the same order. How can I use 'Hold' here?

Comment: @rainer I added several examples that I hope you will find of use and interest.

Answer (score 5):

Would this do, or does the ordering matter?

```
    Clear@func
    func /: func[a_] func[b_] := func[Flatten@{a, b}]
    g[1] + g[2] + g[3] + g[1]*g[3] + 3*g[1]*g[2] + 6*g[1]*g[2]*g[3]/. g[a_] -> func[{a}]
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `ReplaceAll` (`/.`)

```
g[1] + g[2] + g[3] + g[1]*g[3] + 3*g[1]*g[2] + 6*g[1]*g[2]*g[3] /. g -> func
```

> ```
> func[1] + func[2] + 3 func[1] func[2] + func[3] + func[1] func[3] 
>         + 6 func[1] func[2] func[3]
> ```

**Edit**

```
g[1] + g[2] + g[3] + g[1]*g[3] + 3*g[1]*g[2] + 6*g[1]*g[2]*g[3] /. { 
g[a_]*g[b_]*g[c_] -> func[{a, b, c}], g[a_]*g[b_] -> func[{a, b}], g[a_] -> func[{a}]}
```

> ```
> func[{1}] + func[{2}] + func[{3}] + 3 func[{1, 2}] + func[{1, 3}] + 6 func[{1, 2, 3}]
> ```

Comment: thanks,I figured that out already, but thats not exactly what I want to do: I want to transform e.g.`6*g[1]*g[2]*g[3]` into `6*func[{1,2,3}]`

Comment: @rainer Like `Cases[6*g[1]*g[2]*g[3], g[x_] -> x, 2]` ?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Thanks for pointing out what the OP wanted, your solution is elegant +1.

Comment: Thanks for the vote.  I wonder if the question is intended to be more general than the example given.  Are the functions `Plus` and `Times` arbitrary?

Answer (score 3):

```
expr = g[1] + g[2] + g[3] + g[1]*g[3] + 3*g[1]*g[2] + 6*g[1]*g[2]*g[3];
expr /. Times[x___:1 , p__g] :> x func[{p}[[All, 1]]]
(* func[{1}] + func[{2}] + func[{3}] + 3 func[{1, 2}] + func[{1, 3}] + 6 func[{1, 2, 3}]*)
```

Comment: I had almost the same: `expr /. Times[a___ : 1, x : __g] :> a func@Join@x /. g -> List`

Comment: @Simon, just noticed that i could save a character using `__g` instead of  `___g` :)

Comment: I would have sworn I tried that pattern and it didn't work.  Anyway, nice work.  I hope you don't mind my edit but your code was invalid syntax in v7 and `All` works for both.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, Thanks for the edit and the vote.