# Double integral 0

Tags: numerical-integration

I am trying to reproduce the results from a paper in Mathematica. This task involves $K$ double integrals of the form

$$\int f(x,y)g(x)dx,$$

where $f(x,y)$ is a bivariate normal density with mean $(-4.08, -3.41)$ and diagonal covariance matrix with diagonal $(1/10,1/21)$, and $g(x)$ is a normal density with mean $\beta_0+\beta_1\xi$ and variance $\sigma_e^2$ (all of them known). I want to obtain this integral as a function of $\xi$.

```
Sigma = {{1/10, 0}, {0, 1/21}}

    {β0, β1, σe} = \
{-2.3, 0.5, 0.0005}



    f[ξ_] := 
 NIntegrate[
  PDF[MultinormalDistribution[{-4.08, -3.41}, Sigma], {η, ξ}]*
   PDF[NormalDistribution[β0 + β1*ξ, σe], \
η], {η, -∞, ∞}]

   Plot[f[t], {t, -10, 10}]
```

This code returns a $0$ for all values of $\xi$, while the true value should not be $0$.

How can I obtain this integral?  What seems to be the problem?  Is it the precision? Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

My impression so far is that the $\sigma_e$ is very small and therefore the densities involved in the integration are very concentrated. This makes difficult the automatic integration.

Comment: You have not defined `ratex` and `ratey`.

Comment: @JonathanShock Thank you for pointing this out. I have defined these variables and included some explanation.

Comment: Take a look at the function you are trying to integrate. It is enormously small. You will have to be extremely careful with the precision in this calculation.

Comment: @JonathanShock Indeed, I have included a comment on this (last paragraph). Maybe this is why the automatic integration (-Inf,Inf) is not identifying a proper integration range.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is the numerical precision that is required for this calculation.

Thankfully the integral can be performed analytically and then the plot can be created. It is actually easier perhaps in this case to create a `ListPlot` though you can do it with a `LogPlot` too:

```
f[ξ_]=Integrate[
PDF[MultinormalDistribution[{-4.08, -3.41}, Sigma], {η, ξ}]*PDF[NormalDistribution[β0 + β1*ξ, σe], \
η], {η, -∞, ∞}]
{#, Log[f[#]]} & /@ Range[-10, 10, 0.1];
ListLinePlot[%]
```

[image: Result of integral]

Comment: Many thanks. You have wisely noticed that the integral can be obtained in closed form. I was comparing my own calculations with the numerical integral and then I came across this issue.

Comment: Update: The range of interest for $f$ is around $(-4.5,-2.5)$. In this range there is no need to use the $\log$.

Comment: Indeed, this is true.

Comment: Jonathan, your alternative interpretation of a recently deleted question was addressed here: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/7836/121

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, many thanks.