# Copy/Pasting a Grid of Numbers from Project Euler

Tags: formatting, project-euler

On Project Euler Problem 11 (link: https://projecteuler.net/problem=11), there is a 20x20 grid of numbers. However, when I pasted it into Mathematica, I got this strange result where the times symbol 'x' is interlaced between the numbers.

Here is an image that shows this (again, this grid is directly copy/pasted from the website): http://i.gyazo.com/6336b0c44a1cb6afef7ee3f962c06522.png

Are there any in-line commands/functions you can use on that mass of numbers so that you can enter everything once and it will return a nicely formatted list/matrix? The only way I could think of, which did not make use of in-line commands, was very tedious: Ctrl+F --> Replace all "x" with "," and then manually entering curly brackets to turn the grid into a list/matrix.

Ideally, I want to turn it into something like {{1,2,3},{4,5,6},{7,8,9}}, but of course with the appropriate elements.

**Edit**: From this StackExchange post ([Cut and paste data from a spreadsheet](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/8997/cut-and-paste-data-from-a-spreadsheet)), I found that

```
data = ImportString["(copy/paste grid here)", "TSV"]
```

works exactly as desired :)

**Edit 2**: Just kidding, the above doesn't work. It doesn't add commas.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is one way to import the grid into *Mathematica*

```
Partition[
 StringCases[
  Import["http://projecteuler.net/problem=11", "Plaintext"], 
  DigitCharacter ..][[10 ;; -8]], 
 20] // ToExpression
```

Comment: Thank you for this :) Can you explain what the ". . " are for? I looked in the documentation for DigitCharacter, and that seems to be paired with the function, kind of like how pure functions involve the pairing of # and &.

Comment: @AisforAmbition It is a [String Pattern](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/StringPatterns.html). `DigitCharacter ..` means one or more digits.

Comment: A problem I ran into was that since this treats every digit as a string and not a standard number, the inside elements cannot be operated upon by the Times function. What can I do if I want to multiply the matrix's first diagonal, for example?

Comment: Ah, thank you very much :)

Comment: @Karsten7., output is the same w/o "Plaintext".

Comment: @alancalvitti Yes, `"Plaintext"` is the default element used by `Import`.

Answer (score 5):

Szabolcs's [Past Tabular Data palette](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/9010/121) still works just like it should.  This palette is so useful it is one of only two I always open on start-up.

If for some reason you are looking for a one-off solution here is mine:

```
Block[{Times = List}, (*paste here*) ] ~Partition~ 20
```

Reference: [Convert head Times to List](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/7836/convert-head-times-to-list/7842#7842)

Comment: Very elegant method, Mr. Wizard. Once again, you've been a tremendous help :) Thank you!

Comment: Nice. `With` and `Module` also work.

Answer (score 1):

Highlight the list and paste into a text file and then

```
t=Import["put path of text file in here","Table"]
t//MatrixForm
```

works for me. Does it work for anyone else?

Comment: No, I get HTML, eventually containing `... {32, 98, 81, 28, 64, 23, 67, 10, "<span", \
"style=\"color:#ff0000;\"><b>26</b></span>", 38, 40, ...`

Comment: It certainly ought to.  This is the basic method without direct copy-and-paste, but it's the one I used for years before the introduction of `ImportString`.

Comment: @alancalvitti Is your browser really copying HTML code?  Which do you use?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Possible confusion: bobbym wrote "put path..." so I used `Import["http://projecteuler.net/problem=11","Table"]`

Comment: @alancalvitti but first **Highlight the list and paste into a text file and then**

Comment: @alancalvitti the text file is on your machine, so put the path of it in between the quotes.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard & bobbym, too many steps: http://www.amazon.com/Smaller-Faster-Lighter-Denser-Cheaper/dp/1610392051

Comment: Hi alancalvitti, hard to argue with that.