# Definition pattern

Tags: evaluation, expression-manipulation, variable-definitions

If you make a definition, for example

```
blah := RandomChoice[{1, 1, 1, 1, 1} -> {1000, 1001, 1002, 1003,1004}]
```

is there any way to programmatically use `blah` to get that second list as an output?  Some pattern of the [`Definition`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Definition.html) or [`FullDefinition`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FullDefinition.html)...?

I know I have the list right there, but later on, after defining `blah`,  I'd like to grab that second list of numbers and use it.

Thanks for any insight you might provide.

Comment: Take a look at `OwnValues[blah]`

Comment: Why not just define `val={1000, 1001, 1002, 1003, 1004}` and then use this to define `blah`?

Comment: yes, absolutely,  I am not so far along with this process that I can't tweak it a bit,  I just thought I might learn something about getting at the parts of an expression, in this case, the definition .  I had seen UpValues and DownValues, but @Kuba mentioned OwnValues, I had no idea... not possible to know every function,  so I thought I would see there was a way, just "in theory"....No idea how to pull apart the result of OwnValues to get the pieces though....!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As commented by Kuba you can extract the desired expression from [`OwnValues`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/OwnValues.html):

```
blah := RandomChoice[{1, 1, 1, 1, 1} -> {1000, 1001, 1002, 1003, 1004}];

OwnValues[blah][[1, 2, 1, 2]]
```

> ```
> {1000, 1001, 1002, 1003, 1004}
> ```

[my `step` function](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/334/121) also works:

```
stepEval[blah][[1, 1, 2]]
```

> ```
> {1000, 1001, 1002, 1003, 1004}
> ```

If you know the definition structure of `blah`, which it seems you must, you could also `Block` a la [Convert head Times to List](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/7836/121#7842):

```
Block[{RandomChoice = # &, Rule = #2 &}, blah]
```

> ```
> {1000, 1001, 1002, 1003, 1004}
> ```

For the future you might consider using this form instead:

```
blah2 = RandomChoice[{1, 1, 1, 1, 1} -> {1000, 1001, 1002, 1003, 1004}] &;
```

It would be used by calling `blah2[]`.  And the part can be extracted with:

```
blah2[[1, 1, 2]]
```

> ```
> {1000, 1001, 1002, 1003, 1004}
> ```