# How to uncompress only the compressed elements in a matrix

Tags: list-manipulation, compression

I have data in a rectangular structure – something like `matrix={{a,b,c},{d,e,f},{g,h,i}}`. The problem is that some of the columns consist of uncompressed data and some not. Now I'm looking for an elegant way to uncompress the whole matrix. Unfortunately `Uncompress[matrix]` doesn't work.

Comment: Do you know which columns are compressed?

Comment: Hi! you asked seven questions, but accepted answers for only two of them. Some of the answers you received in the (still) unaccepted questions are very good. I think you should go thru them and accept the better ones.

Comment: yes I do know, but it can vary from case to case. So a general solution would be more convenient;-)

Comment: @Verde you are right. Got really perfect answers indeed. Will acept them!

Comment: Also, are you aware of [vote casting](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/130046/when-should-i-vote)? It is very important to enhance the visibility of good questions and answers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a matrix, and compress a column

```
a = RandomInteger[10, {3, 3}]
b = Transpose@{a[[1]], Compress /@ a[[2]], a[[3]]}
```

Uncompress it:

```
Quiet@Map[Check[Uncompress[#], #] &, a, {2}]
```

**Edit**

Instead of `Quiet[]` you could use `Off[Uncompress::string]` so other error messages are not hindered

Comment: Better to use `ReplaceAll` with a pattern `str_String /; StringMatchQ[str, StartOfString ~~ DigitCharacter ~~ ":" ~~ __] :> Check[Uncompress[str], str, Uncompress::corrupt]`?

Comment: it seems as if it doesnt work in my case. Maybe because the compressed part can be again a list. In that case I would like to write only the 7th element into the uncompressed matrix.

Comment: @rainer Why don't you then tell us what your "case" is?  Your question is vague and this is the most that can be said without divining your thoughts

Comment: @OleksandrR. I am not aware that the `:` is documented. If it is, you are right

Comment: ok, now it works. Thx!

Answer (score 4):

Here is a way to only uncompress elements that have been compressed. Note that using *Mathematica*'s `Compress` returns a string starting with `<number>:`, so we need to `Uncompress` only those elements that are strings and start with that.

```
Clear@uncompress
uncompress[s_String] /; StringMatchQ[s, DigitCharacter ~~ ":" ~~ ___] := Uncompress@s
uncompress[x_] := x
```

Comment: The characters "1:e" only appear at the beginning for version 1 compression. Version 2 seems to have "2:G". I would tend to consider only the version number and colon to be part of the header proper since I don't know where the "e" or "G" come from...

Comment: Is the `:` documented anywhere?

Comment: @OleksandrR. There is a version 2 of `Compress`? I've only ever seen 1:e, but I've changed it to `DigitCharacter ~~ ":"` since you say you've seen `2:G`

Comment: @Verde Trying to find it, but not sure if it is

Comment: @Verde it's not documented, but only versions 1 and 2 currently exist, and they both have `DigitCharacter ~~ ":"`, so... (To compress something using the version 2 method, use `Compress[expr, Method -> {"Version" -> 2}]`.)

Comment: @OleksandrR. If it is not documented, I prefer to stay away of it. Sometimes messing with undocumented features is  convenient, but this is not the case

Comment: @Verde the fact that `Uncompress` emits a message when passed something other than a string representing compressed data isn't documented either, but your answer relies on it. By requiring the parameter to be a string of a certain form rather than passing everything indiscriminately, you reduce the chances of encountering side effects or passing some garbage that `Uncompress` may choke on. Of course the optimum solution is avoid creating data structures that require heuristics to reinterpret in the first place...

Comment: @OleksandrR. If you look at the first comment I posted under the question, you will understand that I am completely aware of those issues. Anyway, my answer doesn't rely on `Uncompress[]` issuing a message, but in the original list not having an uncompressed element that matches a thing that could be uncompressed. The fact that `Compress[]` and `Uncompress[]` are not bijective worsens the thing a little (details in the comments [here](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/633/193))

Comment: @Verde I wasn't claiming that you weren't aware of the potential problems, but just that there are difficulties with both approaches that are not easily avoided by relying only on what is documented. Your answer depends on `Check`, which is tied to the existence of messages. If you don't want to assume that, `SameQ` could be used, but one must take care not to allow evaluation to proceed too far before doing the comparison. Something like [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/1447) would be needed as a wrapper.

Comment: @OleksandrR. Yeap. But seems an overkill for a problem that should be solved by good design :)