# Obtain input expression from history without evaluating

Tags: evaluation, kernel, history

I typed and evaluated an expression, but deleted it from the notebook. For instance, suppose it was

```
In[1]:= Round@SessionTime[]
Out[1]= 2
```

I now want to retrieve the input so that I can edit it again.

I know Mathematica keeps the history of evaluated expressions in `In`. But if I try to access it directly `In[123]`, rather than giving the unevaluated input expression, it evaluates it again:

```
In[2]:= In[1]
Out[2]= 10
```

If I use `Hold` to suppress evaluation, then `In[...]` doesn't get evaluated, so I don't see the input:

```
In[3]:= Hold[In[1]]
Out[3]= Hold[In[1]]
```

How can I retrieve the input expression in an editable form, without evaluating it?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In addition to assigning to `In`, the [Mathematica main loop](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/TheMainLoop.html) assigns the input to `InString` before it is parsed as an expression. You can then retrieve `InString[1]` and parse the result with `ToExpression`, wrapping it in `Defer` to prevent it from evaluating immediately:

```
In[5]:= ToExpression[InString[1], StandardForm, Defer]
Out[5]= Round[SessionTime[]]
```

You can then edit and evaluate the resulting expression.

If you want to process the output programmatically, it will be more convenient to use `Hold` in place of `Defer`.

Also, note that `InString` is listable, so if you're not sure of the exact input number you can pass a range, like `InString[Range[10, 20]]`.

Comment: How can I actually get copy-pasteable text?  If I use your example on itself, ``In[6]:= ToExpression[InString[1], StandardForm, Defer]``, I get ``Out[6]:= RowBox[{"ToExpression", "[", 
  RowBox[{RowBox[{"InString", "[", "5", "]"}], ",", "StandardForm",
     ",", "Defer"}], "]"}]``.  I don't want all those ``RowBox``'s and whatnot.  What I actually want is ``Out[6]:= ToExpression[InString[1], StandardForm, Defer]`` (perhaps wrapped with some sort of ``Hold``-like container.)

Comment: OK: just figured it out.  See my top-level answer.

Answer (score 11):

The input is stored as a downvalue in the definition of `In`. If you've only typed a few expressions, run

```
Definition@In
```

which prints a list of all the values associated with the symbol `In`, and copy from the line `In[1] := Round[SessionTime[]]`.

But if you've typed hundreds of expressions, or expressions whose plain-text representations are long (like images), this is hard to use. To extract only a specific input number, use pattern matching:

```
In[4]:= Hold[In[1]] /. DownValues[In]
Out[4]= Hold[Round[SessionTime[]]]
```

Answer (score 3):

Both methods of Mechanical snail work but with some side effects: the `DownValues` method will alter the original input string a little, and the `ToExpression` method as is will produce a large number of `RowBox`es. A simplified method example is:

```
7/29/18 11:39:33 In[259]:= InString[219] // ToExpression // DisplayForm

7/29/18 11:39:33 Out[259]//DisplayForm= FindMinimum[(Log@ktgtht-Log@65.8902)^2+(Log@skgtht-Log@5.99378)^2,#/.Rule->List,MaxIterations->5000]&@{q->0.1,k->0.1,l->0.3}
```

Answer (score 3):

This is a natural application of `step` from [How do I evaluate only one step of an expression?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/334/121)

```
In[1] // step
```

> ```
> Round[SessionTime[]]
> ```

The output is wrapped in [`HoldForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/HoldForm.html); this can be substituted as desired using [`Apply`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Apply.html).