# Join lists in a list of lists

Tags: list-manipulation

What's the best way to join two consecutive lists in a list of lists ?

For example if I have the list

```
x = {{1}, {2}, {3}, {4}}
```

and I want to get in x

```
{{1}, {2, 3}, {4}}.
```

I want to join arbitrary positions.

**Edit**

I want to do this using the least amount of extra memory. Imagine that instead of having numbers I have big lists.

Comment: Could you explain why not just `{{1, 2}, {3, 4}}` or `{{1, 2}, {3}, {4}}` instead of `{{1}, {2, 3}, {4}}` ?

Comment: Maybe give a more detailed example. Is it the 2nd and 3rd elements that should be joined or the 2nd and 3rd *last* elements that should be joined? ...or maybe the middle 2 elements joined?? To much ambiguity.

Comment: what I mean by my comment is what result do you want from this list: `{{1}, {2}, {3}, {4}, {5}}`

Comment: By using part I think the answer of 2013 is the most memory efficient.

Comment: Your edit is important information since I'm sure some of these answers would be quite different if they knew up front that you are working with big lists rather than 4 integers.

Answer (score 7):

```
l = {{a}, {b}, {c}, {d}};
j[l_, from_, to_] := {Sequence @@ l[[1 ;; from - 1]], Join @@ l[[from ;; to]], 
                      Sequence @@ l[[to + 1 ;;]]}

j[l, 2, 4]
(*
->{{a}, {b, c, d}}
*)
```

Comment: This is a bit terse. The OP may well need and deserve a little explanation to go with it.

Comment: @m_goldberg Feel free to improve the answer in any way you feel it should be done. The OP isn't asking for a Mma course, so it's up to you to interpret his/her need.

Comment: @m_goldberg Please don't take the above comment as derogatory. We deal here with users having from none to very advanced Mma knowledge. Faysal has been active here for a long time, so I guess he's able to untangle this piece of code

Comment: I got your point and didn't take any offense. Rather than edit your answer, I decided to offer one of my own,

Comment: @belisarius Since i'm not sure if it is worthy of a question on it's own, how would the code differ if you would wish to combine lists by two in a larger set of lists. For example the input would be:
`{{a},{b},{c},{d},{e},{f}, ...} `
and the result would be like:
`{{a,b},{c,d},{e,f},...}`

Comment: @user350 `Join @@@ Partition[{{a}, {b}, {c}, {d}, {e}, {f}}, 2]`

Comment: @belisarius Works nice! thanks:) What about if one of those lettes represented a whole list and on would want the result to look like:
`{{{a},{b}},{{c},{d}},{{e},{f}}}`
ok i've found it myself, sorry. 
it is `Join @ Partition[{{a}, {b}, {c}, {d}, {e}, {f}}, 2]`

Answer (score 7):

Belisarius' answer works well if you are willing to work with indexes. If you prefer to work in terms of the list elements rather than their positions, here is a rule-based solution.

```
innerJoin[data : {{_} ..}, a_, b_] := 
  data /. {x___, y : PatternSequence[{a}, ___, {b}], z___} :> {x, Flatten[{y}], z}

innerJoin[{{1}, {2}, {3}, {4}}, 2, 3]
```

> {{1}, {2, 3}, {4}}

```
innerJoin[{{a}, {b}, {c}, {d}}, a, c]
```

> {{a, b, c}, {d}}

Edit -- new and improved algorithm featuring the under appreciated `PatternSequence` :-)

Comment: Now with the OP's edit, I don't see how specifying the starting and ending elements would be a good idea if he wants to join 2 consecutive big lists. The `Flatten` would also fail if the elements are lists themselves

Comment: @Rojo. You're right but I didn't have that information when I wrote this answer.

Answer (score 5):

```
list = {{1}, {2}, {3}, {4}}
```

I asked some questions in my comments but in the absence of clarification about what you want, i.e. will this **always** be applied to **4 element** lists, why not just this:

```
list[[2]] = Flatten[list[[{2, 3}]]];
list[[3]] = Sequence[];
list

(* {{1}, {2, 3}, {4}} *)
```

or if you want to make it a function -- probably unnecessary because it is a straightforward two step process:

```
newList[list_List] := Module[{tmp = list}, tmp[[2]] = Flatten[tmp[[{2, 3}]]];
tmp[[3]] = Sequence[]; tmp]
```

**Edit**

Since you've said in your edit 4 hours ago that your actual example is big lists in place of the 4 numbers so you probably won't want to display output

```
list[[2]] = Flatten[list[[{2, 3}]]];
list[[3]] = Sequence[];
list;
```

or

```
list[[2]] = Flatten[list[[{2, 3}]]];
list = Delete[list, 3];

newList2[list_List] := Module[{tmp = list}, tmp[[2]] = Flatten[tmp[[{2, 3}]]];
Delete[tmp, 3]]
```

Comment: You should note that `list[[3]] = Sequence[];` does not delete elements; evaluation must take place.  Do that and you'll get my vote as I was going to suggest the same method.

Comment: If you mean that you have to evaluate `list` as a final step why is that problem? In all methods you have to undertake evaluation steps. In this one the final step is different to other methods.

Comment: Reading his edit if he is actually working with large lists he probably won't want to display. I'll make a revision for that case.

Comment: Mike, my point is that after making a `list[[__]] = Sequence[]` assignment you haven't deleted those elements (which I think you know).  This could be very confusing if you then make further assignments with `Part` as you won't get what you (might) expect.  A simple `list = list;` would do but so would `Drop` (more flexible than `Delete`).  Anyway, +1.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard yes I kind of understood what you were asking but I guess the thing was the question -- for me -- was ambiguous w.r.t intended real usage (though his edit sheds a little more light). The answer as provided gives an output cell with a list in the format he was seeking.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Is there actually a way to directly see the result of `list[[3]]=Sequence[]`, i.e., `{1,2,Sequence[],...}`? Maybe this is a useless question but I'm curious...

Comment: @sebhofer IMHO that's *far* from a useless question.  You can see the value by using [my `step` function](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/1447/121), e.g. `list = Range@5; list[[3]] = Sequence[]; step[list]`.  I wrote that function to handle just such cases as this.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard That's a quite complicated construction, it will take me a while to parse it properly. It seems to be very useful though!

Answer (score 4):

Using `TakeList` (new in 11.2) we can get the desired result by
successively taking n elements from `list`.

```
list = {{1}, {2}, {3}, {4}};

Join @@@ TakeList[list, {1, 2, All}]
```

{{1}, {2, 3}, {4}}

Or, using István Zachar's example:

```
list = {{1}, {2}, {3}, {4}, {5}, {6}, {7}, {8}}

Join @@@ TakeList[list, {2, 4, All}]
```

{{1, 2}, {3, 4, 5, 6}, {7, 8}}

Answer (score 3):

A bit more general version with `Drop` and `ReplacePart`:

```
list = List /@ Range@8
{from, to} = {3, 6}; (* specify first and last positions to be joined *)
ReplacePart[Drop[list, {from + 1, to}], from -> Join @@ Take[list, {from, to}]]
```

> ```
> {{1}, {2}, {3}, {4}, {5}, {6}, {7}, {8}}
>
> {{1}, {2}, {3, 4, 5, 6}, {7}, {8}}
> ```

With `ReplaceAll` and `Repeated`:

```
list /. {x : Repeated[_, {from-1}], y : Repeated[_, {to-from+1}], z___} :> {x, Join@y, z}
```

> ```
> {{1}, {2}, {3, 4, 5, 6}, {7}, {8}}
> ```

Answer (score 3):

Trying to keep up with @eldo

We can use [**`FoldPairList`**](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FoldPairList.html) + [**`TakeDrop`**](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TakeDrop.html) which were both introduced in **v10.2**

```
Join @@@ FoldPairList[TakeDrop, {{1}, {2}, {3}, {4}}, {1, 2, All}]
```

to give

> `{{1}, {2, 3}, {4}}`

or testing with the other list that was used in the answers

```
Join @@@ 
 FoldPairList[
  TakeDrop, {{1}, {2}, {3}, {4}, {5}, {6}, {7}, {8}}, {2, 4, All}]
```

> `{{1, 2}, {3, 4, 5, 6}, {7, 8}}`

Comment: (+1) Nicely done, mate! :-)

Comment: @E.Chan-López thanks a lot! :-)

Answer (score 2):

Using `PartitionRagged`:

```
joinLists[l_, a_, b_] := Join @@@ 
                           Internal`PartitionRagged[#, 
                             {a, b, Length@# - Total@{a, b}}] &@l

joinLists[{{1}, {2}, {3}, {4}}, 1, 2]

(*{{1}, {2, 3}, {4}}*)

joinLists[{{1}, {2}, {3}, {4}, {5}, {6}, {7}, {8}}, 2, 4]

(*{{1, 2}, {3, 4, 5, 6}, {7, 8}}*)
```

Comment: (+1) and almost 10 now!