# Convert a symbol name to a Symbol and pass it as an argument to a HoldAll function unevaluated

Tags: programming, function-construction, evaluation, symbols, hold

```
ClearAll[holdingFunction];
SetAttributes[holdingFunction, HoldAll];
holdingFunction[a_] := Print[FullForm[Hold[a]]]; (* Actual implementation is different *)

ClearAll[evaluateOneStep];
evaluateOneStep[expr_] := (* Some magic *);

ClearAll[invokeHoldingFunction];
invokeHoldingFunction[symbolName_String] := 
  holdingFunction[evaluateOneStep[Symbol[symbolName]]];

ClearAll[fail];
fail := Abort[];
```

I need to find such an implementation for `evaluateOneStep` so that, for example, `invokeHoldingFunction["fail"]` prints `Hold[fail]` — I need only the symbol itself to be constructed from its name, but no definition that may exist for it to be applied until the function `holdingFunction` decides to `ReleaseHold`. Could you please suggest how to do this?

Comment: Check the third argument of `ToExpression`

Comment: As for the "one step" issue, see [(334)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/334/).

Comment: To make the advice of @Rojo more explicit, you need `invokeHoldingFunction[symbolName_String]:= ToExpression[symbolName,InputForm,holdingFunction]`.