# How do I insert OwnValues inside a held expression without evaluating it?

Tags: expression-manipulation, variable-definitions, hold

Here is a very long and complicated expression, which we abbreviate as `a`.  I store it using `SetDelayed` because I want to perform algebraic manipulations on it:

```
ClearAll[a];
a := 1 + 1
```

Here is a really complicated function `f` with attributes `HoldFirst` that operates on its first argument.  It counts the number of times `1` appears in its first argument.

```
ClearAll[f];
SetAttributes[f, HoldFirst];

f[input_] := Module[{expr=Hold[input]},
  Count[expr,1,{0,Infinity}]
]
```

As you can see, directly inserting the complicated expression works, but not if you insert the abbreviation `a`:

```
f[1+1]
(*2*)      (* good *)

f[a]
(*0*)      (* not good *)
```

The reason it doesn't work is because `Hold` doesn't allow inserting a definition.   So, in the second example, `Count` is seeing the symbol `a` and not the expression `1+1` to which it points.

**Question:**  How do I insert `OwnValues` verbatim inside a held expression without evaluating it?

---

*SIMPLE EXAMPLE*

```
ClearAll[a];
a := 1 + 1
```

Here is a sample held expression containing symbols which may or may not have `OwnValues`:

```
Hold[a + b + c]
```

How do I insert the RHS of the definition of `a` verbatim into the held expression, so that the result is this?:

```
Hold[(1 + 1) + b + c]
```

I have the following (which may or may not be fruitful):

```
Hold[a + b + c] /. (symb_Symbol /; OwnValues[symb] =!= {} :> 
   RuleCondition[First[OwnValues[symb]]])

(*  Hold[(HoldPattern[a] :> 1 + 1) + b + c] *)
```

Comment: All other values `UpValues` `DownValues` `SubValues` etc.. should not be inserted into the held expression.

Comment: Why not just `Hold[a+b+c]/.OwnValues[a]`?

Comment: @LeonidShifrin This assumes you know that `a` is the symbol with `OwnValues`.  How do I make this replacement for all symbols which have `OwnValues` without knowing beforehand which ones have them?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard It does seem familiar, but I can't find a dupe right now.

Comment: Related: [(40165)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/40165/121), [(46535)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/46535/121)

Comment: @Kuba No, I was just having another Senior Moment. :-p

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
ClearAll[a, b];
a := 1 + 1
b = Sqrt
```

Is this acceptable?

```
foo = # /. Join @@ Cases[#, s_Symbol :> OwnValues[s], ∞, Heads->True] &;

foo @ Hold[a + b[c]]
```

> ```
> Hold[(1 + 1) + Sqrt[c]]
> ```

---

#### Update

As OP has noticed I've missed the fact that `ReadProtected` symbols won't show its `OwnValues`.

We could do something like `s_Symbol /; FreeQ[ Attributes[s], ReadProtected]` but why should we skip that symbol if we can just evaluate it to get its `OwnValue`?

Here's alternative approach:

```
ClearAll[a, b];
SetAttributes[{b, d}, ReadProtected]
a := 1 + 1
b = Sqrt
d := 1 + 2

foo = # /. Join @@ Cases[#, s_Symbol :> If[
   FreeQ[Attributes[s], ReadProtected],
   OwnValues[s],
   {HoldPattern[s] :> Evaluate@s}
  ], 
  \[Infinity], Heads -> True] &;

foo@Hold[a + b[c] + I + d]
```

> ```
> Hold[(1 + 1) + Sqrt[c] + I + 3]
> ```

As you can see `d` is inserted but not as `1+2`, that's the price of `ReadProtected`. We could `Unprotect` but it wouldn't work for `Locked` symbols. So at the end it's up to OP how to handle those cases.

Comment: Ninja'd me there, +1

Comment: This is quite nice.

Comment: And, it's easy to prevent heads from getting replaced by simply changing `Heads->False`.

Comment: I found something funny:  if you try `foo @ Hold[a + I b[x]]`, you'll get `General::readp` messages and it doesn't work.  This seems to be related to `I` being held is different from when it is processed by the kernel...

Comment: Nice.  Some bonus use-cases would be: (1) Don't substitute symbols when they are being passed to HoldAll / HoldAllComplete / HoldFirst / etc functions (2) If performing #1, include pure functions with the same attributes (can't get such attributes with `Attributes`, though, so method may be different), and (3) Don't substitute symbols when they are being passed to `Module` / `Block` / `With` (probably a freebie if performing the other use-cases).  Maybe I'll come up with something.