# Specifying non-conflicting PlotTheme options

Tags: plotting, bugs, color, undocumented, plot-themes

A bug or limitation in 10.0.0 affects a few of these examples; it was resolved in 10.1.0.

---

I am trying out Mathematica 10 on https://programming.wolframcloud.com. `$PlotTheme` interested me a lot because it finally produces nice plots (probably) without the need of fine tuning of every plot. However, the options are conflicting each other and there seems to be some hiding options. For example (figures available at https://www.wolframcloud.com/objects/0caeabc9-81ba-4c6c-a51d-64f06c644a40),

```
(* This get thick lines *)
LogPlot[{1/x, x,2x, E^x},{x,1,10},PlotTheme->{"ThickLines"}]

(* This get monochrome *)
LogPlot[{1/x, x,2x, E^x},{x,1,10},PlotTheme->{"Monochrome"}]

(* There is no monochrome or thick lines here *)
LogPlot[{1/x, x,2x, E^x},{x,1,10},PlotTheme->{"Monochrome","ThickLines"}]
```

As another example,

```
(* Didn't get open markers or monochrome, but at least get thick *)
ListPlot[{{{1,2},{2,4},{3,7},{4,9}},{{1,3},{2,4}}},PlotTheme->{"Monochrome","OpenMarkersThick"}]

(* After adding frame, markers completely changed *)
ListPlot[{{{1,2},{2,4},{3,7},{4,9}},{{1,3},{2,4}}},PlotTheme->{"Monochrome","Frame","OpenMarkersThick"}]
```

Is it possible to make those themes non-conflicting with each other? The theme seems perfect for me is as follows:

(1) The lines are solid, dashed, dotted, ... ("Monochrome")

(2) The lines are colored. (e.g. "VibrantColor")

(3) Framed ("Frame").

(4) Larger labels ("LargeLabels"). At best thicker lines ("ThickLines").

(5) Setting apply both to `Plot` and `ListPlot` (to put in $PlotTheme instead of tuning every plot).

But I am not able to get all of them satisfied -- once `Plot` looks fine, `ListPlot` looks ugly. Is it possible to get some non-conflicting fine tunings once and apply everywhere?

Comment: I would certainly report your difficulties to support@wolfram.com

Comment: This could be a bug, as help says it is supposed to combine them.

Comment: It is a bug in my opinion. It appears partly dependent on order, but that is not consistent. For example `{"Frame","Monochrome"}` works correctly but `{"ThickLines","Monochrome"}` does not affect line thickness and `{"Monochrome","Frame"}` yields neither feature.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the comments! I added `bugs` tag to the post.

Comment: This appears to have been improved somewhat in 10.0.1; the first example appears to work.  However the other examples are still broken.

Comment: After some spelunking it is my conclusion that the present behavior is not a bug, merely under-documented.  I shall therefore mark this as "fixed in 10.0.1" for the change noted at that time.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The details of the styles associated with various themes can be accessed using  the function `ResolvePlotThemes` in the `Charting` context.

For example:

```
Grid[{#, Column@(Charting`ResolvePlotTheme[#, ListPlot] /. 
   HoldPattern[PlotMarkers -> _] :>  Sequence[])} & /@ {"Monochrome", "Frame", "Vibrant"}, 
   Dividers -> All]  (* removed the part related to PlotMarkers to save space *)
```

[image]

Similarly, for the themes `"ThickLines"` and  `"OpenMarkersThick"`

```
 Grid[{#, Column@(Charting`ResolvePlotTheme[#, ListPlot] /. 
      HoldPattern[PlotMarkers -> _] :> Sequence[])} & /@ 
                     {"ThickLines", "OpenMarkersThick"}, 
       Dividers -> All]
```

[image]

So ...

(1) Depending on the order in which the themes appear on the RHS of `PlotTheme->_` the conflicts are resolved in favor of earlier (or later ?) ones, that is, later (earlier ?) appearances of a given option are simply ignored.

(2) However, you can mix/match the relevant styling pieces from various themes. For example:

```
pltstylm = "DefaultPlotStyle" /. 
        (Method /. Charting`ResolvePlotTheme["Monochrome", ListLinePlot]);
pltstylv = "DefaultPlotStyle" /. 
         (Method /.  Charting`ResolvePlotTheme["Vibrant", ListLinePlot]);
pmrkrs = PlotMarkers /. Charting`ResolvePlotTheme["OpenMarkersThick", ListLinePlot];
frm = Frame /. Charting`ResolvePlotTheme["Frame", ListLinePlot];
frmstyl =  FrameStyle /. Charting`ResolvePlotTheme["Frame", ListLinePlot];
grdlnsstyl =  GridLinesStyle /.  Charting`ResolvePlotTheme["Monochrome", ListLinePlot];

ListPlot[{{{1, 2}, {2, 4}, {3, 7}, {4, 9}}, {{1, 3}, {2, 4}}},
    PlotStyle->pltstylv, PlotMarkers->pmrkrs,Frame->frm,Joined->True,
    FrameStyle->frmstyl,GridLines->Automatic,
    GridLinesStyle->grdlnsstyl, ImageSize ->700]
```

[image]

```
ListPlot[{{{1, 2}, {2, 4}, {3, 7}, {4, 9}}, {{1, 3}, {2, 4}}},
    PlotStyle->pltstylm, PlotMarkers->pmrkrs,Frame->frm,Joined->True,
    FrameStyle->frmstyl, GridLines->Automatic,GridLinesStyle->grdlnsstyl,
    ImageSize ->700]
```

[image]

```
 dashedVbrnt = Join[pltstylm,Rest@pltstylm];
 dashedVbrnt[[All, 1]] = pltstylv[[All, 1]];  
 Plot[Evaluate@Table[BesselJ[n, x], {n, 5}], {x, 0, 10}, ImageSize ->400, 
    PlotStyle -> dashedVbrnt, PlotTheme -> "Detailed"]
```

[image]

```
ListPlot[Table[BesselJ[n, x], {n, 5}, {x, 0, 10,.3}], Filling->Axis,
   ImageSize ->500, PlotStyle ->dashedVbrnt, PlotMarkers->pmrkrs, Joined->True,
   PlotTheme ->"Detailed"]
```

[image]

Answer (score 15):

#### The present state of affairs

The kind of manual manipulation demonstrated by [kglr](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/125/kglr) should theoretically not be necessary.  There may have been some problems in the initial version 10 release but in either 10.0.2 or 10.1.0 many Themes already combine correctly.  Emulating his penultimate example:

```
Plot[Evaluate@Table[BesselJ[n, x], {n, 5}], {x, 0, 10}, ImageSize -> 400, 
 PlotTheme -> {"Monochrome", "VibrantColor", "Detailed"}]
```

[image]

The last example doesn't work out so well as `"Monochrome"` dominates the plot:

```
ListLinePlot[Table[BesselJ[n, x], {n, 5}, {x, 0, 10, .3}], Filling -> Axis, 
 ImageSize -> 500, 
 PlotTheme -> {"Detailed", "Monochrome", "OpenMarkersThick", "VibrantColor"}]
```

[image]

#### Low-level PlotTheme definitions

To find out what went wrong with `"Monochrome"` we can look at its actual definition as I detailed in the **Advanced method** section of [Is it possible to define a new PlotTheme?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/54545/is-it-possible-to-define-a-new-plottheme/54637#54637).  First load [`step`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/1447/121), then:

```
Defer @@ step @ System`PlotThemeDump`resolvePlotTheme["Monochrome", "ListLinePlot"]
```

> ```
> Themes`SetWeight[
>  Join[{AxesStyle -> System`PlotThemeDump`monoColor, 
>    BaseStyle -> System`PlotThemeDump`monoColor, 
>    FrameStyle -> System`PlotThemeDump`monoColor, 
>    FrameTicksStyle -> System`PlotThemeDump`monoColor, 
>    GridLinesStyle -> 
>     Directive[System`PlotThemeDump`monoColor, AbsoluteThickness[1], 
>      AbsoluteDashing[{1, 2}]], LabelStyle -> System`PlotThemeDump`monoFont, 
>    "DefaultThickness" -> Directive[CapForm["Butt"], AbsoluteThickness[1.6]], 
>    "DefaultColor" -> System`PlotThemeDump`monoColor, 
>    "DefaultDashing" -> {AbsoluteDashing[{}], AbsoluteDashing[{6, 2}], 
>      AbsoluteDashing[{2, 2}], AbsoluteDashing[{6, 2, 2, 2}], AbsoluteDashing[{12, 2}], 
>      AbsoluteDashing[{12, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2}], AbsoluteDashing[{24, 2, 8, 2}], 
>      AbsoluteDashing[{24, 2, 2, 2}]}, TicksStyle -> System`PlotThemeDump`monoColor}, 
>   System`PlotThemeDump`resolvePlotTheme["PlotMarkers", 
>    "ListLinePlot"]], System`PlotThemeDump`$MonochromeWeight]
> ```

Of note:

- Among other things the `BaseStyle` option is being set;
- The Theme options are given a weight of `` System`PlotThemeDump`$MonochromeWeight ``

#### `BaseStyle` precedence

[`BaseStyle`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BaseStyle.html) takes precedence over the method used by `"VibrantColor"` (which is to set the value of `` System`PlotThemeDump`$ThemeColorIndexed `` as can be seen from viewing *its* definition).  Therefore we can prevent that problem by setting `BaseStyle -> {}` as user options take further precedence:

```
ListLinePlot[Table[BesselJ[n, x], {n, 5}, {x, 0, 10, .3}], Filling -> Axis, 
 ImageSize -> 500, 
 PlotTheme -> {"Detailed", "Monochrome", "OpenMarkersThick", "VibrantColor"}, 
 BaseStyle -> {}]
```

[image]

#### `SetWeight` precedence

The plot markers are still wrong however.  This is because `` System`PlotThemeDump`$MonochromeWeight `` is higher than `` System`PlotThemeDump`$ComponentWeight `` (used by most other Themes) and this gives it priority.  If we momentarily lower that value with `Block` we finally get the target styling. :

```
Block[{System`PlotThemeDump`$MonochromeWeight = 0.4},
 ListLinePlot[Table[BesselJ[n, x], {n, 5}, {x, 0, 10, .3}], Filling -> Axis, 
  ImageSize -> 500, 
  PlotTheme -> {"Detailed", "Monochrome", "OpenMarkersThick", "VibrantColor"}, 
  BaseStyle -> {}
 ]
]
```

[image]

#### Customization

For future use it would be better to [define a new Theme](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/54545/is-it-possible-to-define-a-new-plottheme/54637#54637) with only the dashing we want:

```
System`PlotThemeDump`resolvePlotTheme["monoDash", "Plot" | "ListPlot" | "ListLinePlot"] :=
  Themes`SetWeight[{"DefaultDashing" -> {AbsoluteDashing[{}], AbsoluteDashing[{6, 2}], 
     AbsoluteDashing[{2, 2}], AbsoluteDashing[{6, 2, 2, 2}], AbsoluteDashing[{12, 2}], 
     AbsoluteDashing[{12, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2}], AbsoluteDashing[{24, 2, 8, 2}], 
     AbsoluteDashing[{24, 2, 2, 2}]}}, System`PlotThemeDump`$ComponentWeight]
```

Now we can use it with other Themes with a weight of `$ComponentWeight` and it just works:

```
ListLinePlot[Table[BesselJ[n, x], {n, 5}, {x, 0, 10, .3}], Filling -> Axis, 
 ImageSize -> 500, 
 PlotTheme -> {"Detailed", "OpenMarkersThick", "VibrantColor", "monoDash"}]
```

[image]

Comment: Is there a way to use this to give some lines lower opacity? Changing monoDash to do `"DefaultOpacity" -> {Opacity[0.5]` seems to have no effect

Comment: @Yaroslav I'm not sure I understand.  You want different opacities specified within the Theme itself?

Comment: Yes, I basically wanted to have first 5 plots series to be standard style, and remaining to be thick and semi-transparent

Comment: @Yaroslav Here is a first attempt: ``System`PlotThemeDump`resolvePlotTheme["Test", "Plot" | "ListPlot" | "ListLinePlot"] := Themes`SetWeight[{PlotStyle -> Join[ColorData[97] ~Array~ 5, Table[Opacity[0.5, Gray], {20}]]}, Themes`$ColorWeight];``  Test:

`Plot[{1 x, 2 x, 3 x, 4 x, 5 x, 6 x, 7 x, 8 x, 9 x, 10 x, 11 x}, {x, 0, 5}, 
 PlotTheme -> "Test"]` -- is that the kind of result you want? -- sorry, I forgot the "thick" part; try `Table[Directive[Thickness[0.01], Opacity[0.5, Gray]], {20}]` instead.

Comment: but it makes them gray, I was thinking something like your "monoDash" theme -- where I could keep existing color and dashing properties, and just apply opacity to some

Comment: @Yaroslav please try ``System`PlotThemeDump`resolvePlotTheme["Test", "Plot" | "ListPlot" | "ListLinePlot"] := Themes`SetWeight[{PlotStyle -> Join[Table[Opacity[1], {5}], Table[Directive[Thickness[0.01], Opacity[0.3]], {20}]]}, Themes`$ColorWeight];``