# What are the standard colors for plots in Mathematica 10?

Tags: plotting, color

Mathematica 10 release appears to have changed the default styling of plots: the most visible changes are thicker lines and different default colors.

Thus, answers to [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5391825/what-are-the-standard-colors-for-plots-in-mathematica) are only valid for Mathematica < 10. For example, plots in this code will not give identical output in Mathematica 10, although they do in version 9:

```
fns = Table[x^n, {n, 0, 5}];
Plot[fns, {x, -1, 1}, PlotStyle -> ColorData[1, "ColorList"]]
Plot[fns, {x, -1, 1}]
```

[image]

So, my question is: what is the new way of getting the default colors to reproduce for own uses?

Comment: Thanks for the Accept.  I added another method if you are interested in only the colors rather than full styling information.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard thanks, this update is really helpful!

Answer (score 145, accepted):

The colors alone are indexed color scheme #97:

```
ColorData[97, "ColorList"]
```

[image]

**Update:** further digging in reveals these `PlotTheme` indexed color relationships:

```
{"Default"   -> 97,  "Earth"       -> 98,  "Garnet"      -> 99,  "Opal"       -> 100,
 "Sapphire"  -> 101, "Steel"       -> 102, "Sunrise"     -> 103, "Textbook"   -> 104,
 "Water"     -> 105, "BoldColor"   -> 106, "CoolColor"   -> 107, "DarkColor"  -> 108,
 "MarketingColor" -> 109, "NeonColor" -> 109, "PastelColor" -> 110, "RoyalColor" -> 111,
 "VibrantColor"   -> 112, "WarmColor" -> 113};
```

The colors are returned as plain `RGBColor` expressions; the colored squares are merely a formatting directive.  You can still see the numeric data with:

```
ColorData[97, "ColorList"] // InputForm
```

> ```
> {RGBColor[0.368417, 0.506779, 0.709798], . . .,
>  RGBColor[0.28026441037696703, 0.715, 0.4292089322474965]}
> ```

You can get a somewhat nicer (rounded decimal) display using standard output by blocking the formatting rules for `RGBColor` using [`Defer`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Defer.html):

```
Defer[RGBColor] @@@ ColorData[97, "ColorList"] // Column
```

> ```
> RGBColor[0.368417, 0.506779, 0.709798]
> . . .
> RGBColor[0.280264, 0.715, 0.429209]
> ```

To get full styling information for the default and other Themes see:

- [How to access new colour schemes in version 10?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/54486/how-to-access-new-colour-schemes-in-version-10)

For example:

```
Charting`ResolvePlotTheme[Automatic, Plot]
```

[image]

(Actually `Automatic` doesn't seem to be significant here as I get the same thing using `1` or `Pi` or `""` in its place; apparently anything but another defined Theme.)

Comment: To find the RGB values of the colors (instead of just displaying them), you can use `ToString/@ ColorData[97, "ColorList"]`. Then, to display these values next to the corresponding color, you can use `Grid@Transpose@{ColorData[97,"ColorList"], ToString/@ColorData[97, "ColorList"]}`. If anyone can find a better method to find the RGB values, I'd love to hear it.

Comment: @seismatica See update.

Comment: Fantastic, that this is so complicated ;)

Comment: @Thomas If you like complicated be sure to read [(87282)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/87282/121) :^)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Do you know what the color scheme for Plot3D is? It seems that the first two colors from the default scheme (#97) for Plot are switched. Thanks!

Comment: @PhysicsCodingEnthusiast No, but I'll try to find out.  It does appear to be the first ten colors of #97 except with the first two reversed.

Comment: @PhysicsCodingEnthusiast It comes from ``System`PlotThemeDump`$ThemeDefaultLighting`` which directly defines its colors from `ColorData[97, "ColorList"][[{2, 1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}]]` so in this case it actually is exactly what it appears to be.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Thank you so much! It is quite strange, nonetheless, that the first two colors are switched.

Comment: I should add that [this thread](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/102422) discusses how to disable the color swatch formatting.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
 fns = Table[x^n, {n, 0, 5}]; 
    Plot[fns, {x, -1, 1}, PlotTheme -> None] 
    Plot[fns, {x, -1, 1}, PlotTheme -> None]
```

Comment: I seem to have read the question quite differently.  I don't think Ruslan is asking how to reproduce the old defaults but rather how to access the directives underlying the new ones.

Comment: Indeed, the old defaults are reproduced by first `Plot` in my example.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, maybe you are right but I thought the way to get color manipulated as he want is to disable the new feature "Theme" so that it is not interfere with the way he used to change the color in V9. In all cases I think you are right that we need not to just disable this feature but rather understand it well so that we can work while the new feature is enabled.