# Are there more pre-existing ColorFunction options?

Tags: plotting, graphics, color

Such as `"DarkRainbow"`, `"Rainbow"`, `"BlueGreenYellow"`, and `"NeonColors"`?

Comment: See here http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ColorData.html

Comment: And here http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/guide/ColorSchemes.html

Comment: Related: [(54629)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/54629)

Answer (score 9):

Choose "Color Schemes" from the Palettes menu.  It has all the colour schemes listed.

[image]

Otherwise you can use [`ColorData`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ColorData.html) to obtain the possible values (as belisarius mentioned).