# Combining Plot and ListPlot using appropriate colours

Tags: plotting, graphics

I have Plot and ListPlot and I want to combine the using Show:

```
plt = Plot[{Cos[x], Sin[x]}, {x, 0, 2}];
plt2 = ListPlot[{{1, 1}, {0.5, 0.5}}];
plt3 = ListPlot[{{0.4, 1}, {0.2, 0.5}}];
Show[plt, plt2, plt3]
```

But the problem is with colouring the ListPlots. Let's say I would like plt2 markers have the same colour as Cos[x] and plt3 the same colour as Sin[x]. How would I do it?

Comment: Why not put the two `ListPlot[]`s together? `plt2 = ListPlot[{{{1, 1}, {0.5, 0.5}}, {{0.4, 1}, {0.2, 0.5}}}];`?

Comment: You could also specify `PlotStyle` colors manually if needed for some reason.  If you wish to match the defaults see [(54629)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/54632/121)

Comment: I am sorry, I wanted an automated solution. I know how to do it manually, but such a solution is rather clumsy and yes, that is trivial. But what I want is a nice automated solution (like use the same colour for listplot as you used for plot).

Comment: In that case, you need to explicitly set `PlotStyle`. Mr. Wizard has already linked you to the thread on how the default colors are generated.

Answer (score 9):

[PlotStyle](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PlotStyle.html) is your Friend.

```
plt = Plot[{Cos[x], Sin[x]}, {x, 0, 2}
   , PlotStyle -> {{Red, Thick}, {Blue, Thick}}];
plt2 = ListPlot[{{1, 1}, {0.5, 0.5}}, PlotStyle -> Red];
plt3 = ListPlot[{{0.4, 1}, {0.2, 0.5}}, PlotStyle -> Blue];
Show[plt, plt2, plt3]
```

[image]