# How to prevent Dynamic activity with color swatches in V10+

Tags: graphics, front-end, dynamic, color

Since version 10, if I type e.g. an `RGBColor` or simply a named color, a dynamic colour swatch is returned.

[image: screenshot]

Same goes for when you e.g. extract colours from a plot (in this case called `p`).

[image: example]

I'm wondering if there is a simple option that I have overlooked to turn this behaviour off. I've had a look through the Options Inspector and system options but there was not anything obvious.

**Edit**

Just to be clear, my preferred solution is to have `RGBColor[1,0,0]` returned or alternatively the swatch without the tooltip and dynamics (just the `Graphics[…]`)

Comment: One way is to clear `FormatValues[RGBColor] =.` after unprotecting it. I'm really wondering whether anyone uses these swatches. I hate them. It's as useful as having `img=..` and then a big inline image on the right side. Awful.

Comment: @halirutan On the contrary, I use them a LOT! I find them more concise and more informative than a triplet of RGB numerals. Though I'm quite good in reading those, swatches save some extra shift-entering for me. It obviously fits in the symbolic nature of _Mathematica_. And of course one always can use [`FullForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FullForm.html) on them.

Comment: @halirutan I use them to colour code the probabilities from classifications but don't want tooltips and for them to be clickable with a colour selection window appearing. In other words for app building it is very annoying.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This should work:

```
SetSystemOptions["TypesetOptions" -> "ColorDirectiveSwatches" -> False]
```

Comment: Thanks Simon. I suspected that there had to be a system option for that

Answer (score 6):

You can disable this interactivity (and keep the swatches) with the [`Deploy`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Deploy.html) function.

> yields a deployed version of expr in which elements such as Slider, InputField, Locator and Button are active, but general editing and selection is disabled.

```
Deploy@Red
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Have you tried it yourself? It does not work for me (tested with versions 10.2 and 10.3.1 on Win7 x64).

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov Of course I've tried it.  Works fine for 10.3.1 and 10.2 on Win 8.1 Pro 64bit.  I use `Deploy` all the time.

Comment: Very strange, here is what I get: [screenshot](http://i.stack.imgur.com/RGtk8.png).

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov Correct. That is what you should get. Notice that you don't get the dynamic colour swatch with all the editing bits which is what he has asked to turn off.

Comment: Thanks, now I see your point. It seems I misunderstood the question: I thought that the OP wants `Red` to return `RGBColor[1, 0, 0]` as it was in the previous versions. BTW the editing palette on my system does not work unless I click the `Advanced` button, seems to be a bug (version 10.3.1). Does it work for you?