# Accessing Plot's default formatting

Tags: plotting, output-formatting

I'd like to plot multiple sets of data, along with trend line fits for each. I can do this by plotting the fits, and then including the data in an `Epilog`. But I'd like the color of the data points to match the color of the curves in `Plot`. Is there an easy way to access the default colors of plots?

I've done what I want here:

[image]

But, I had to do clunky things. First, I assigned the output of the `Plot` to a variable `out`. Then in the `Epilog`, I called stuff like `out[[1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2]]` to get the correct color. There has to be a better way.

TIA

Comment: Maybe not quite what you asked, but an easy way to extract the colors used in some plot is to use `out//Cases[#,_RGBColor,Infinity]&`. More generally if you want the colors to be the same you can combine the `ListPlot` and `Plot` with `Show`, specifying in both the same list of colors to be used for the plot (using the `PlotStyle` option)

Comment: The default color of `Plot` can be found [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/54629/what-are-the-standard-colors-for-plots-in-mathematica-10).

Comment: In addition to the two marked duplicates (links inserted above your question) you may find [(17252)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/17252/121) of interest, especially xslittlegrass's `restylePlot2`.  Please try to apply what you learn from all of these to your problem.  If you have trouble let me know and I'll try to help; if I can't you can post a new question.

Comment: Thanks all. Sorry about the dup.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`Show`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Show.html) to combine a `ListPlot` of the data and `Plot` of the fit functions. If the data is listed in the same order as the fit functions then the data will match the fit color.

```
dataA = {{0, 21}, {4, 18}, {9, 10}};
dataB = {{0, 45}, {5, 44}, {10, 38}};
dataC = {{0, 32}, {6, 22}, {11, 26}};

fitA = LinearModelFit[dataA, x, x];
fitB = LinearModelFit[dataB, x, x];
fitC = LinearModelFit[dataC, x, x];

Show[
 Plot[{fitA[x], fitB[x], fitC[x]}, {x, 0, 12},
  PlotLabels -> {"Data A", "Data B", "Data C"}, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}],
 ListPlot[{dataA, dataB, dataC}]
 ]
```

[image]

Comment: You can just use `Plot[{modelA /. fitA, modelB /. fitB}, {x, 0, 10}]`, instead of going to the effort to create a function that you can pass the variable `x` to.

Comment: …and if you use `LinearModelFit[]`, you can get a function that is quite easily plotted.