# How to assign two sets of colors for two `ParametricPlot`?

Tags: plotting, color

I would like to use `ParametricPlot` twice and use `Show` to put them together:

```
p1 = ParametricPlot[ 
  Evaluate@
   Table[ReIm[r ( Cos[u] + I  Sin[u])], {r, Range[0.1, 0.9, .2]}],
  {u, -Pi/2, 3 Pi/2},
  PlotStyle -> Thick,
  PlotRange -> 1.2,
  AxesStyle -> Opacity[0.2],
  ImageSize -> 300]

p2 = ParametricPlot[ 
  Evaluate@
   Table[ReIm[
     r ( Cos[u] + I  Sin[u])], {u, {Pi/6, 3 Pi/4, 5 Pi/4, -Pi/4}}],
  {r, 0.01, 0.9999},
  PlotStyle -> {Thick},
  PlotRange -> 1.2,
  AxesStyle -> Opacity[0.1],
  ImageSize -> 300]
```

[image] [image]

One can see that the four colors in `p2` are the same as the first four colors in `p1`. How can I make `p2` with a set of colors different from that of `p1`?

---

One might manually choose different colors for lines in `p2`. I'm interested in a way that makes colors in `p1` and `p2` look as if they are from one `ParametricPlot`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`PlotStyle`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PlotStyle.html) and [`ColorData`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ColorData.html) to specify the color of the lines.

p1

```
PlotStyle -> Table[ColorData[97, i], {i, 1, 5}]
```

p2

```
PlotStyle -> Table[ColorData[97, i], {i, 6, 9}]
```

All together:

```
Show[
 p1 = ParametricPlot[
   Evaluate@
    Table[ReIm[r (Cos[u] + I Sin[u])], {r, Range[0.1, 0.9, .2]}], {u, -Pi/2, 3 Pi/2}, 
   PlotStyle -> Table[Directive[Thick, ColorData[97, i]], {i, 1, 5}], 
   PlotRange -> 1.2, AxesStyle -> Opacity[0.2], ImageSize -> 300],
 p2 = ParametricPlot[
   Evaluate@
    Table[ReIm[r (Cos[u] + I Sin[u])], {u, {Pi/6, 3 Pi/4, 5 Pi/4, -Pi/4}}], {r, 0.01, 0.9999}, 
   PlotStyle -> Table[Directive[Thick, ColorData[97, i]], {i, 6, 9}], 
   PlotRange -> 1.2, AxesStyle -> Opacity[0.1], ImageSize -> 300]
 ]
```

Comment: Thanks. Is there something special about that `97`?

Comment: 97 is the default color palette used by *Mathematica*

Comment: Found this related: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/54632/664 Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to @Young's answer, I see that it might be a better idea to use another color "scheme" for `p2`, so that the colors would look more different from those in `p1`:

[image] [image]

```
p1 = ParametricPlot[ 
  Evaluate@
   Table[ReIm[r ( Cos[u] + I  Sin[u])], {r, Range[0.1, 0.9, .2]}],
  {u, -Pi/2, 3 Pi/2},
  PlotStyle -> 
   Table[Directive[Thickness[0.01], ColorData[97, i]], {i, 1, 5}],
  PlotRange -> 1.2,
  AxesStyle -> Opacity[0.2],
  ImageSize -> 250]

p2 = ParametricPlot[ 
  Evaluate@
   Table[ReIm[
     r ( Cos[u] + I  Sin[u])], {u, {Pi/6, 3 Pi/4, 5 Pi/4, -Pi/4}}],
  {r, 0.01, 0.9999},
  PlotStyle -> 
   Table[Directive[Thickness[0.01], ColorData[101, i]], {i, 6, 9}],
  PlotRange -> 1.2,
  AxesStyle -> Opacity[0.1],
  ImageSize -> 250]
```

[image]