# What is the default blue for the Plot?

Tags: plotting, color, legending

My code is a simple function which I plot for two different times `t`

```
up[x_, t_] := un*Exp[I*((kr + I*ki)*x - (wr + I*wi)*t)];

un = 1;
kr = 2*Pi;
ki = 0.1;
wr = 0.1;
wi = 0.1;

a0 = Show[
  Plot[Re[up[x, 1]], {x, 0, 10}, PlotRange -> All, 
   AxesLabel -> {Style["x", FontSize -> 13], 
     Style["q'", FontSize -> 13]}, 
   PlotLegends -> 
    PointLegend[{Blue}, {"\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(t\), \(0\)]\)"}]], 
  Plot[Re[up[x, 5]], {x, 0, 10}, PlotRange -> All, 
   AxesLabel -> {Style["x", FontSize -> 13], 
     Style["q'", FontSize -> 13]}, PlotStyle -> Orange, 
   PlotLegends -> 
    PointLegend[{Orange}, {"\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(t\), \
\(1\)]\)>\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(t\), \(0\)]\)"}]]]
```

[image]

How to set the same blue tone from `Plot` (default) to the legend label?

Comment: `ColorData[97][1]` at least in version 11

Comment: Here's an answer  with this and more: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/54632/38205

Comment: You can see all the colors used, including axes, with `InputForm@DeleteDuplicates@Cases[plot, _?ColorQ, Infinity]`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Plot[{Re[up[x, 1]],Re[up[x, 5]] }, {x, 0, 10}, PlotRange -> All, 
   AxesLabel -> {Style["x", FontSize -> 13],  Style["q'", FontSize -> 13]}, 
   PlotLegends -> PointLegend[Automatic,{Subscript[t,0]  ,Subscript[t,1]>Subscript[t,0]}]]
```

[image]

Using `ColorData[97,"ColorList"][[;;2]]` in place of `Automatic` gives the same result.

Answer (score 3):

If you do not specify a color, the legend will get it from the plot:

```
a0 = Show[
  Plot[Re[up[x, 1]], {x, 0, 10}, PlotRange -> All, 
   AxesLabel -> {Style["x", FontSize -> 13], 
     Style["q'", FontSize -> 13]},
   PlotLegends -> PointLegend[{"\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(t\), \(0\)]\)"}]],
  Plot[Re[up[x, 5]], {x, 0, 10}, PlotRange -> All, 
   AxesLabel -> {Style["x", FontSize -> 13], 
     Style["q'", FontSize -> 13]}, PlotStyle -> Orange,
   PlotLegends -> 
    PointLegend[{"\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(t\), \(1\)]\)>\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(t\), \(0\)]\)"}]]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]