# ParametricPlot table of complex functions in several graphs

Tags: plotting, graphics, legending, parametric-functions, style

Assume that I have a table of complex functions like

`Clear[p]
Clear[M]
M = 10;
G = Table[Sin[i p] + p  I, {i, M}]`

I want to ParametricPlot them in graphs, each graph contains only one of them. What should I edit in the following code

`ParametricPlot[Evaluate[ReIm /@ G], {p, 0, 2},
 AxesLabel -> (Style[#, 12, Bold] & /@ {Re, Im}),
 PlotRange -> {{-1.2, 1.2}, {0, 2}}, ImageSize -> 600,
 PlotLegends -> Placed[G, Right]]`

Which plot them in the following single graph:

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
plots = ParametricPlot[Evaluate[ReIm@#], {p, 0, 2}, 
     AxesLabel -> (Style[#, 12, Bold] & /@ {Re, Im}), 
     PlotRange -> {{-1.2, 1.2}, {0, 2}}, ImageSize -> 600, 
     PlotLegends -> Placed[#, Right]] & /@ G;
Grid[Partition[plots, 2]]
```

Comment: Also, to use the standard colors for different lines, use `PlotStyle -> ColorData[97, "ColorList"][[i]]`, refer to https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/54629/what-are-the-standard-colors-for-plots-in-mathematica-10

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to  display one plot at a time, consider using [`Manipulate`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Manipulate.html)

```
Clear[p]
M = 10;
G = Table[Sin[i p] + p I, {i, M}];

Manipulate[
 Legended[
  ParametricPlot[
   ReIm@G[[i]], {p, 0, 2},
   AxesLabel -> (Style[#, 12, Bold] & /@ {Re, Im}),
   PlotRange -> {{-1.2, 1.2}, {0, 2}},
   ImageSize -> 300,
   ColorFunction -> (ColorData["Rainbow"][#3] &)],
  Labeled[
   BarLegend[{"Rainbow", {0, 2}}],
   Style["p", 12, Bold], Top]],
 {{i, 5}, Range[Length[G]], ControlType -> SetterBar}]
```

[image]