# Apparent bug in ImageHistogram

Tags: image-processing, image

When building a simple image with only red
Rred = Image[Table[{r, 0, 0}, {r, 0, 255}, {g, 0, 255}], "Byte"],
[image]
the corresponding histogram displays badly:
each channel has a wrong colour
ImageHistogram[Rred, Appearance -> "Separated"]
[image]

Answer (score 8):

That is because you did not specify explicitly which color space you use in your image. The colors of the histograms are therefore the first three colors from the [default Mathematica color scheme](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/54632/75628).

The following works as expected:

```
imageRed = 
 Image[Table[{r, 0, 0}, {r, 0, 255}, {g, 0, 255}], "Byte", 
  ColorSpace -> "RGB"]

ImageHistogram[imageRed, Appearance -> "Separated"]
```

[image]

Comment: You are right, I missed it. Thanks