# Use TraditionalForm (or something similar) in AxesLabel/PlotLegends

Tags: plotting, fonts, style

I use the following command to export plots to PDF which I then use in latex:

```
plot = Plot[x^2, {x, -2, 2}, AxesLabel -> {x, x^2}, 
       PlotLegends -> {"Function f(x) = x^2"}]
Export[NotebookDirectory[] <> "SimplePlot.pdf", plot]
```

[image]

Now the "problem" is that the font of $x$, $x^2$ and $f(x)=x^2$ is not at all similar to the standard font of latex. I found that the command `TraditionalForm` produces output with a font that seems to fit latex much better:

[image]

But simply putting `AxesLabel -> {TraditionalForm[x], TraditionalForm[x^2]}` for example does not change the plot's font. So how can I change the font in my plot to the one that `TraditionalForm` offers? And no, I do not want to change the font in latex. ;)

Comment: The url's for your images don't have public access

Comment: That's twice the same link ...

Comment: My location has blocked uploads on SE, so I had to use google. 
The direct links to the images are https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B8kIki5yrvFbZnREdVg0TlZPeTQ/edit?pli=1 and 
https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B8kIki5yrvFbYTNGajBadDVWU0k/edit?pli=1. I am very sorry about the inconvenience.

Comment: Does `PlotTheme->"ItalicLabels"` give something close to what you need?

Comment: @wuyingddg solution works as expected on 10.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (June 29, 2014). If you like to **change the plot's font** you can add `LabelStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Times", 14, GrayLevel[0]}`. As long as the Font is installed on your System, the Font will be embedded.

Comment: @kguler It is almost perfect. But it literally makes everything italic (even the ticks on the axes), so a 1 looks (alomost) like a 7. Is there any way of specifying which part of the plot is made italic and which not?

Comment: @Lou Your tip worked. And `plot=Plot[x^2,{x,-2,2},AxesLabel->{x,x^2},PlotLegends->{Style["Function f(x) = x^2",Italic]},LabelStyle->{FontFamily->"Times",14,GrayLevel[0]}]` gives the desired result (on Win7, 64 Bit, Mathematica 10.0).

Comment: Tom, add the option `TicksStyle -> Plain`..

Comment: @kguler It works! Thanks a lot. But how does one learn all these little details ...?

Comment: @Tom, v10 added quite a few of these little details:)  [this Q/A](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/54486/125) may be useful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
plot = Plot[x^2, {x, -2, 2},  AxesLabel -> {Style[x, 20], Style[x^2, 20]}, 
     PlotTheme->"ItalicLabels",TicksStyle->Plain,
     PlotLegends -> {Row[{Style["Function  ",20,FontSlant-> "Plain",FontFamily->"Times"], 
        Style[HoldForm[ f[x]  =   x^2],20,FontSlant->"Oblique",FontFamily->"Times"]}] }]
```

[image]

Or, instead of using `PlotTheme->"ItalicLabels"` you can directly use the option settings for `LabelStyle` and `TickStyle` as follows

```
plot = Plot[x^2, {x, -2, 2},   AxesLabel -> {x,  x^2},
    LabelStyle (* or BaseStyle *) ->
          Directive[FontFamily->Times,FontSlant->"Oblique",FontSize->20],
    TicksStyle->Directive[FontSize->14,FontSlant->Plain],
    PlotLegends -> {Row[{Style["Function  ",FontSlant-> "Plain",FontFamily->"Times"], 
        Style[HoldForm[ f[x]  =   x^2],FontSlant->"Oblique",FontFamily->"Times"]}] }]
```

to get the same picture as above.

To get the settings for the theme `"ItalicLabels"` use

```
Charting`ResolvePlotTheme["ItalicLabels", Plot]
```

[image]

See also: [this Q/A](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/54486/125) and [this one](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/51846/125)

Comment: If we write `Plot[x^2,{x,-2,2},AxesLabel->{Style[x,20],Style[x^2,20]},PlotLegends->{Style[HoldForm[Function f[x]=x^2],20]},LabelStyle->{FontFamily->"Times"}]`, then `=` is not tilted.

Comment: @Tom, it seems that we need to also add `FontSlant->"Oblique"`...

Comment: This is just nitpicking, but why do you add Oblique? This is exactly what makes the equal sign `=` crooked, which one would probably want to avoid.

Comment: Oh ... I thought you wanted the `=` sign look slanted:)

Answer (score 2):

*Mathematica* 9 use `TraditionalForm` by default

```
Plot[x^2, {x, -2, 2}, AxesLabel -> {x, x^2}]
```

[image]

*Mathematica* 10 also use `TraditionalForm`, but fonts are different. So we have to change fonts back

```
Plot[x^2, {x, -2, 2}, AxesLabel -> {x, x^2}, AxesStyle -> FontFamily -> "Times"]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The function `Style` and `HoldForm` may be helpful

```
plot = Plot[x^2, {x, -2, 2}, 
  AxesLabel -> {Style[x, 20, " TraditionalForm"], 
    Style[x^2, 20, " TraditionalForm"]}, 
  PlotLegends -> {HoldForm[Function f[x] = x^2] // TraditionalForm}]
```

f(x) should be f[x] so that it can be convert into TraditionalForm

[image]

Comment: This only seems to work in Mathematica 9, but I am using version 10, in which your example (unfortunately) gives the same output as my screenshot above. :/