# How to specify custom graph styles for GraphStyle?

Tags: graphs-and-networks, options, style, plot-themes

There is a way to specify custom themes for plots ([Is it possible to define a new PlotTheme?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/54545/89)), but themes do not apply to `Graph` objects, not even to `GraphPlot`. Graph options are set by the `GraphStyle` option with which one can select from a few built-in styles:

```
GraphElementData["GraphStyle"]
```

> ```
> {Automatic, "BackgroundBlack", "BackgroundBlue", ..., "VintageDiagram"}
> ```

However, `GraphElementData` definitions cannot be accessed (the function itself is only tangentially touched in the documentation), so I have no idea how to come up with a theme that works as a built-in one. The obvious solution is to set up default options that are passed on to `Graph` directly or via `SetOptions`, but I'd like to have a more integrated method where I can call my graph like this:

```
Graph[{1 -> 2, 2 -> 3, 3 -> 1}, GraphStyle -> "MyGraphTheme"]
```

and have a result like this:

```
Graph[{1 -> 2, 2 -> 3, 3 -> 1}, Background -> GrayLevel@.15,
 EdgeStyle -> Directive[Green, Thick], VertexLabels -> "Name", 
 VertexLabelStyle -> Directive[Orange, 16], ImagePadding -> 20, ImageSize -> 200]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Ultimately, I'd like to use the same themes for graphs that are available for plots.

Comment: One possible solution (to the problem described in the bounty offer) is to have a function which takes graph options, combines them with a "theme", then returns new graph options. This is probably the safest way. The function has to handle per-vertex and per-edge options, as well as global options.  A nicer way would be to hook into GraphStyle, but that feels risky.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you are willing to mess around with the internals of Mathematica, I think the necessary graph style code is at top level. So:

```
Options[addGraphStyle] = {
    BaseStyle->Automatic,
    DirectedEdges->Automatic,
    EdgeLabels->None,
    EdgeLabelStyle->Automatic,
    EdgeShapeFunction->Automatic,
    EdgeStyle->Automatic,
    GraphHighlightStyle->Automatic,
    Options->{},
    VertexLabels->None,
    VertexLabelStyle->Automatic,
    VertexShape->Automatic,
    VertexShapeFunction->Automatic,
    VertexSize->Automatic,
    VertexStyle->Automatic
};

addGraphStyle[style_String, opts:OptionsPattern[]] := Internal`WithLocalSettings[
    Unprotect[GraphComputation`SetGraphStyle],

    Replace[
        OptionValue[EdgeLabels], 
        v_ :> Set[GraphComputation`SetGraphStyle[style, EdgeLabels], v]
    ];
    Replace[
        OptionValue[VertexLabels], 
        v_ :> Set[GraphComputation`SetGraphStyle[style, VertexLabels], v]
    ];
    Replace[
        OptionValue[Options],
        v_ :> Set[GraphComputation`SetGraphStyle[style, Options], v]
    ];
    Map[
        Replace[
            OptionValue[#],
            {
            Automatic :> Quiet @ Unset[GraphComputation`SetGraphStyle[style, #]],
            v_ :> Set[GraphComputation`SetGraphStyle[style, #], v]
            }
        ]&,
        {
        BaseStyle, DirectedEdges, EdgeLabelStyle, EdgeShapeFunction, EdgeStyle,
        GraphHighlightStyle, VertexLabelStyle, VertexShape, VertexShapeFunction, VertexSize, VertexStyle
        }
    ];
    GraphComputation`SetGraphStyle[style<>"3D", rest__] := GraphComputation`SetGraphStyle[style, rest],

    Protect[GraphComputation`SetGraphStyle]
]
```

Example:

```
addGraphStyle[
    "Example",
    {
    VertexLabels->"Name",
    EdgeStyle->Directive[Green, Dashed]
    }
]
```

Visualization:

```
Graph[{1->2, 2->2}, GraphStyle->"Example"]
Graph[{1->2, 2->2}, GraphStyle->"Example", EdgeStyle->Thickness[.02]]
```

[image]

For the OP example, we have:

```
addGraphStyle[
    "Istvan",
    Options->{Background->GrayLevel@.15, ImagePadding->20, ImageSize->200},
    EdgeStyle->Directive[Green, Thick],
    VertexLabels->"Name",
    VertexLabelStyle->Directive[Orange, 16]
]

Graph[{1->2, 2->3, 3->1}, GraphStyle->"Istvan"]
```

[image]

Comment: It looks like exactly what I wanted. I'll play with it tomorrow (it's late now), and will award the bounty if it works.  (Will also release a set of nice styles using this functionality.)

Comment: @Szabolcs There is an issue with resetting styles back to their defaults, which could be fixed by adding a check for the old values, or by adding a `removeGraphicStyle` function.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work for `Graph3D`. I mean that when the corresponding graph options would affect Graph3D, the graph style that was created with this function won't have an effect on it.

Comment: @Szabolcs I added `Graph3D` support.

Comment: If you've seen my answer then you know that I am ready to mess around with the internals of Mathematica, even modify built-ins : ) Nice solution, earned the accept! On the other hand, I'm still awaiting public and polished theme-setting functionality in general.

Answer (score 7):

**Update 2016.8.13.**

**In *Mathematica* v11.0, `Graph` were modified to be able to use directly the `PlotTheme` option.** While there are reliable ways to construct new themes (see [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/54545/89) and [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/51846/89)), unfortunately the theme system is still not fully compatible with graphs. At the moment, you cannot add `Graph`-specific rules like `` Themes`AddThemeRules["myGraph", Graph, VertexLabelStyle -> Green] `` to have any effect when called e.g. `Graph[{1->2, 2->3, 3->1}, PlotTheme -> "myGraph"]`.

---

I've constructed a more-or-less safe way to do this. I aimed for the more general case: to directly use available plotting themes with graphs, at least the relevant options. I even started to wonder why `PlotTheme` was not designed to cooperate with all graphics object (like `Graph`, `Graphics`, `GeoGraphics`, etc.).

```
(* Define a new theme *)
Themes`AddThemeRules[
  "Dark", {Background -> GrayLevel@.15, 
   EdgeStyle -> Directive[Green, Thick], VertexLabels -> "Name", 
   VertexLabelStyle -> Directive[Orange, 16], ImagePadding -> 20, 
   ImageSize -> 200, PlotRange -> All, 
   DefaultPlotStyle -> Directive[Green, Thick], 
   LabelStyle -> Directive[Orange, 12]}];

Unprotect@Graph;
Graph[arg__, pre : OptionsPattern[], PlotTheme -> t_, post___] := 
  If[MemberQ[GraphElementData@"GraphStyle", t],
   Graph[arg, pre, GraphStyle -> t, post],
   Module[{th = Charting`ResolvePlotTheme[t, Graph]},
    (* Exclude functional ticks and method as Graph can't handle these *)
    th = DeleteCases[th, _[FrameTicks | Ticks, _?(MemberQ[Flatten@{#}, _Function] &)] |
    _[Method, _]];
    Graph[arg, FilterRules[
      DeleteDuplicatesBy[Flatten@{pre, theme, post}, First], 
      Options@Graph]]
    ]];

{Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 10}, PlotTheme -> "Dark"],
 Graph[{1 <-> 2, 2 <-> 3, 3 <-> 1}, PlotTheme -> "Dark"],
 Graph[{1 <-> 2, 2 <-> 3, 3 <-> 1}, PlotTheme -> "Scientific", 
  ImageSize -> 200],
 Graph[{1 <-> 2, 2 <-> 3, 3 <-> 1}, 
  EdgeStyle -> Directive[Thick, Red], PlotTheme -> "Dark"],
 Graph[{1 <-> 2, 2 <-> 3, 3 <-> 1}, PlotTheme -> "DiagramGold"]}
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

As you can see, it recognizes built-in `GraphStyle`-s. User-options take precedence over themes, if supplied before `PlotTheme`. Trying some of the built-in plot themes:

```
Multicolumn[
 Graph[{1 <-> 2, 2 <-> 3, 3 <-> 1}, PlotTheme -> #, PlotLabel -> #, 
    ImageSize -> 150] & /@ {"Business", "Detailed", "Marketing", 
   "Minimal", "Monochrome", "Scientific", "Web", "Classic"}, 4, 
 Appearance -> "Horizontal"]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 1):

On the first try, I can't find a way to make something like " `GraphTheme` " work. Perhaps there is a way to do it, but I don't see it.

A quick hack to make this work without using themes is something like:

```
myGraphOptions = {Background -> GrayLevel@.15, 
 EdgeStyle -> Directive[Green, Thick], VertexLabels -> "Name", 
 VertexLabelStyle -> Directive[Orange, 16]}
Graph[{1 -> 2, 2 -> 3, 3 -> 1}, myGraphOptions]
```

This appears to have the desired effect, more or less. (Not sure if you wanted the `ImageSize` or `ImagePadding` in the "theme" -- I didn't include it.)

One thing to keep in mind though is if you want to override some of these, you'll want to put those options before the `myGraphOptions`.

```
Graph[{1 -> 2, 2 -> 3, 3 -> 1}, EdgeStyle -> Red, myGraphOptions]
```

Note that in this case, the edges are red, but also *not* thick.

But I agree a "theme" type of construction for `Graph` would be better.

Comment: Thanks Kellen for the effort, but this is exactly the referred "obvious solution" I want to avoid. Sorry, no cigar for this :)

Comment: Of course, I do understand. I thought this would be a good answer in the case nothing more useful comes up, especially if another reader comes to this question hoping for an answer but without the same foreknowledge as you and I. This might be useful to such a person.