# Limited styles in the Monochrome plot theme

Tags: plotting, style, plot-themes

It seems like `PlotTheme -> "Monochrome"` produces up to 8 different dashing styles for `Plot`. I know one way to overcome this is to use `ListLinePlot` and use `PlotMarkers` to produce more combinations. However, I am wondering if there are simpler ways to just assign more dashing styles in the Monochrome theme?
For example, as seen below, the styles repeat themselves.

```
Plot[Evaluate@Table[2 p + y, {p, 0, 1, 0.1}], {y, 0, 4}, 
 PlotTheme -> "Monochrome"]
```

[image]

Comment: It's more than you get with the normal plot theme, there the colors start repeating after `p=5`

Comment: A humble recommendation to the poser:  Ask the *minimally informative* question.  There's no need to complicate your question by using functions requiring Exclusions, or large number of PlotPoints, or to choose the size and FontFamily, etc. to learn what you seek.  `Plot[Evaluate@Table[a x^2, {a, 1, 2, .1}], {x, 0, 1},
 PlotTheme -> "Monochrome"]` suffices.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork good point. I'll change it.

Comment: @JasonB. They repeat after 5? Which ones?

Comment: @rcollyer - they repeat after 5 if you squint..... that blue followed by a yellow looks similar to the first blue followed by a yellow.  But yeah, I was clearly wrong

Comment: @JasonB. The thing is, it is much easier to create a list of different colors in the normal plot theme than a list of different distinguishable styles in monochrome themes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One solution would be to double the number of plot styles under this theme by making them gray.  So you would have 8 black styles, followed by 8 gray styes.

Learning from the answers [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/51846/9490), you could do this via

```
System`PlotThemeDump`resolvePlotTheme["Monochrome", "Plot"] = 
 ReplaceAll[
  System`PlotThemeDump`resolvePlotTheme["Monochrome", "Plot"],
  HoldPattern[Rule["DefaultDashing", dashing_List]] :> 
   Rule["DefaultDashing", Join[dashing, Thread[{Gray, dashing}]]]];
```

Now you can have up to 16 distinct styles,

```
f[x_] := x^4 + x
g[x_] := x^2
tSet = Table[f[x] + c*g[x], {c, -4, 8}];
Plot[Evaluate@tSet, {x, -2, 2}, PlotTheme -> "Monochrome", 
 PlotLegends -> "Expressions"]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 2):

```
PlotStyle -> (Dashing[#]& /@ Table[i, {i, .01, .09, .01}])
```

or whatever style you like:

```
{Dashing[{.02, .05, .01}],Dashing[.04], Dashing[{.01, .02, .01, .06}],...}
```

or of course `AbsoluteDashing`

Comment: This works but loses the first seven wonderful default styles of the Monochrome theme. Can it be done somehow to be used after the default  styles have been exhausted?

Comment: You're making this harder than it need be.  Blow up a plot and then *by hand* enter the dashing values for the five styles (matching the rendered lines), and then you're done.  You'll save *so* much time if you do this.  [Over and out.]

Comment: I can adopt your suggestion by using `AbsoluteDashing[{d1, d2, d3,..}]` that has the ability to produce all different dashing styles that I want. Thanks!