# Plot with PlotLegends -> "Expressions" doesn't show all expressions in Legend

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation, legending

So I'm basically trying to plot a table that has multiple versions of 
(x^4)+(cx^2)+x, with c being an integer.

I've gotten the expressions to all be graphed, however I can't seem to have the legend show all the expressions and their matching linestyle. It's currently only showing 8 out of the 13. Here's what I have

```
f[x_] := x^4 + x
g[x_] := x^2
Plot[y = f[x], {x, -2, 2}, PlotStyle -> Black]
tSet = Table[f[x] + c*g[x], {c, -4, 8}]
Plot[Evaluate@tSet, {x, -2, 2}, PlotTheme -> "Monochrome", 
 PlotLegends -> "Expressions"]
```

Here is the table

```
{x - 4 x^2 + x^4, x - 3 x^2 + x^4, x - 2 x^2 + x^4, x - x^2 + x^4, 
 x + x^4, x + x^2 + x^4, x + 2 x^2 + x^4, x + 3 x^2 + x^4, 
 x + 4 x^2 + x^4, x + 5 x^2 + x^4, x + 6 x^2 + x^4, x + 7 x^2 + x^4, 
 x + 8 x^2 + x^4}
```

By the way, I'm using PlotTheme -> "Monochrome" because I need to print in black and white!

Any help would be lovely :)

Comment: It seems you are limited by the plot theme - "Monochrome" doesn't have 13 distinct styles.

Comment: i was thinking the same thing, but when i used a normal styling (with colors) it looked like the colors used were repeated well (although that might just be my eyes) Would you happen to now a way to distinguish all 13 without color?

Comment: @DrunkOnHotCoco-I had the same issue with making out the different colors.  But just try this: `Plot[{x, x + 1, x + 2}, {x, -3, 3}, PlotStyle -> {Red, Blue, Red}, 
 PlotLegends -> "Expressions"]`

Comment: ah, I understand. Thanks!

Comment: If your publication can distinguish between gray and black lines, you could do something like [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/156508/9490).  (I answered there as that question came first)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you only have 8 different plot styles, but 13 different functions.  The "Expressions" option will only show as many legend items as there are distinct styles,

```
Plot[{x, x + 1, x + 2}, {x, -3, 3}, PlotStyle -> {Red, Blue, Red}, 
 PlotLegends -> "Expressions"]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]