# Better automatic style selection for many distinct series in one plot?

Tags: plotting

The default style selection of `ListLinePlot` makes it hard to tell things apart, is there some easy way to apply a better (automatically chosen) set of distinct styles? IE, things like varying thickesses, dash style, etc

Here's what I end up with default styles

[image]

Comment: `PlotTheme` comes to mind.

Comment: hm, all the plot themes either use colors, or dash/thickness styles, it seems to make 8 series distinct there would need to be a plot theme that uses both

Comment: There is a post about creating [custom plot themes](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/54545/is-it-possible-to-define-a-new-plottheme) but the technique used in the answers is undocumented and advanced.

Answer (score 1):

I found what I needed in mrwizard's answer here -- [Specifying non-conflicting PlotTheme options](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/51846/specifying-non-conflicting-plottheme-options/87282#87282)

The trick was to specify another theme just for dashing, and combine it with default Theme:

```
System`PlotThemeDump`resolvePlotTheme["monoDash", 
  "Plot" | "ListPlot" | "ListLinePlot"] := 
 Themes`SetWeight[{"DefaultDashing" -> {AbsoluteDashing[{}], 
     AbsoluteDashing[{}], AbsoluteDashing[{}], 
     AbsoluteDashing[{5, 5}], AbsoluteDashing[{5, 5}], 
     AbsoluteDashing[{5, 5}], AbsoluteDashing[{}], 
     AbsoluteDashing[{}]}}, System`PlotThemeDump`$ComponentWeight]
System`PlotThemeDump`resolvePlotTheme["monoThick", 
   "Plot" | "ListPlot" | "ListLinePlot"] :=

  Themes`SetWeight[{"DefaultThickness" -> {AbsoluteThickness[3.0], 
      AbsoluteThickness[3.0], AbsoluteThickness[3.0], 
      AbsoluteThickness[1.6], AbsoluteThickness[1.6], 
      AbsoluteThickness[1.6], AbsoluteThickness[1.6], 
      AbsoluteThickness[1.6], AbsoluteThickness[1.6]}}, 
   System`PlotThemeDump`$ComponentWeight];    


seqLen = 100;
nSeq = 9;
seq := Accumulate[
   Table[RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[]], {seqLen}]];
seqs = Table[seq, {nSeq}];
ListLinePlot[seqs, PlotLegends -> {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}, 
 PlotTheme -> {"monoDash", "monoThick"}]
```

[image]

Comment: What does `SetWeight` function from `Themes\`` context does? Is there some reference where one can read more about it?