# easy modification of existing theme

Tags: stylesheet, plot-themes

For the most part, the "Monochrome" theme is useful.  However the default inclusion of plot markers in a `ListLinePlot` was imo a horrible mistake (a design bug), both inconsistent with other styles and most often unwanted.  I'm tired of turning markers off over and over (note that `SetOptions` is overridden by the theme).  So I would like to *very simply* (i.e., in a couple lines) define a new theme that is identical except for the new setting `PlotMarkers->None` for `ListLinePlot`.  I started designing a new style with `` Themes`AddThemeRules `` but it proved to be a rabbit hole.  Suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As explained nicely by @MrWizard in his answers [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/54637/36508) and [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/87282/36508), you'll want to use `` System`PlotThemeDump`resolvePlotTheme `` for anything non-trivial when working with themes. Here, we can use this to easily create a new theme that inherits from `"Monochrome"`, except that it changes one setting for `ListLinePlot`:

```
System`PlotThemeDump`resolvePlotTheme["MonochromeFixed", p_] :=
 System`PlotThemeDump`resolvePlotTheme["Monochrome", p]
(* special case for ListLinePlot *)
System`PlotThemeDump`resolvePlotTheme["MonochromeFixed", p : "ListLinePlot"] :=
 System`PlotThemeDump`resolvePlotTheme["Monochrome", p] /. 
   (PlotMarkers -> _) :> (PlotMarkers -> None)
```

No more `PlotMarkers` by default:

```
ListLinePlot[RandomReal[{0, 1}, {3, 3}], PlotTheme -> "MonochromeFixed"]
```

[image]

Other plots are just as with `"Monochrome"`:

```
BarChart[RandomReal[{0, 1}, {3, 3}], PlotTheme -> "MonochromeFixed"]
```

[image]