# How to access new colour schemes in version 10?

Tags: color, version-10

Many colour schemes and colour functions can be accessed using [`ColorData`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ColorData.html).

Version 10 introduced new default colour schemes, and a new customization option using [`PlotTheme`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/PlotTheme.html).  The colour themes accessible with `PlotTheme` have both discrete colour schemes and gradients.

Is there a standard way to access these?  I.e. get a colour function that take a real argument in $[0,1]$ and returns a shade, or one that takes an integer argument and returns a colour, as with `ColorData`.

Comment: That's a good question. I know the new default colors are `ColorData[97]` with some slight variations between different plots.

Comment: The first two colours are occasionally exchanged, e.g. in `Histogram`.

Comment: Right, and sometimes lightened/darkened depending on the general needs of the plot type.

Comment: I notice that you haven't Accepted kguler's answer.  I added my own including a mapping for `ColorData` indexed colors and information on how to find the gradient used by e.g. `BarChart[{Range@99}, PlotTheme -> "Sunrise"]`.  Is this more to your liking?  Is there something else I can look for to improve my answer?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I forgot to accept!

Comment: This question is duplicated at http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/54629/what-are-the-standard-colors-for-plots-in-mathematica-10, but in my opinion the accepted answer to the duplicate is more helpful than either answer to this question.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

**Update 2:** The content and organization of `$PlotThemes` in versions 10 and 9 are very different. In Version 10

```
 Charting`$PlotThemes
```

gives

[image]

whereas in Version 9, the content is organized around Charting/Plotting functions (See the picture in original post below.)

The color schemes can be obtained using:

```
 "Color"/. Charting`$PlotThemes
 (* BackgroundColor, BlackBackground, BoldColor, ClassicColor, CoolColor,
    DarkColor,GrayColor, NeonColor,PastelColor, RoyalColor, VibrantColor, WarmColor, 
    DefaultColor, EarthColor, GarnetColor, OpalColor, SapphireColor, SteelColor,
    SunriseColor, TextbookColor, WaterColor} *)

 Grid[{#,Row@(("DefaultPlotStyle"/.(Method/. 
   Charting`ResolvePlotTheme[#,   ListPlot]))/.
      Directive[x_,__]:>x)}&/@("Color"/. Charting`$PlotThemes),Dividers->All]
```

[image]

**Update:** The function that defines the color schemes and styles seems to be `ResolvePlotTheme`, which is in the `Charting` context in both Version 9 and 10.

```
?Charting`ResolvePlotTheme
(* too long  to copy here ... *)
```

For example,

```
Charting`ResolvePlotTheme["Vibrant", ContourPlot]
(* {BaseStyle -> GrayLevel[0.5], BoundaryStyle -> None, 
   ColorFunction -> (Blend[{Hue[0.5, 1, 0.5], Hue[0.35, 0.5, 0.7], 
                     Hue[0.17, 0.7, 0.9]}, #1] &), ContourStyle -> GrayLevel[1, 0.5],
   GridLines -> Automatic, 
   GridLinesStyle -> Directive[GrayLevel[0.5], Dashing[{0, Small}]], 
   Method -> {"GridLinesInFront" -> True}}  *)
```

So, one can access the color functions used in these themes using something like;

```
 Grid[{#, ColorFunction /. Charting`ResolvePlotTheme[#, ContourPlot]} & /@
          ("ContourPlot" /. Charting`$PlotThemes), Dividers -> All]
```

[image]

More generally, one can get the settings for `ColorFunction`, `ChartStyle`, `PlotStyle` `BaseStyle` etc. using a similar approach:

```
Grid[{#, Column@FilterRules[Charting`ResolvePlotTheme[#, PieChart], 
         {ColorFunction, ChartStyle, BaseStyle}]} & /@
  ("PieChart" /. Charting`$PlotThemes), Dividers -> All]
```

[image]

---

`PlotTheme` seems to work in Version 9.0.1.0 as an undocumented feature:

```
?*`*PlotTheme*
```

[image]

After `Unprotect` and `ClearAttributes[--,ReadProtected]` one can access some details. For example:

```
?Charting`$PlotThemes
```

[image]

And, despite syntax hightlighting suggesting error, they work as expected:

```
Row[Plot[Table[BesselJ[n, x], {n, 5}], {x, 0, 10}, Evaluated -> True, 
ImageSize -> 400, PlotLabel -> Style[#, 20], 
Charting`PlotTheme -> #] & /@ {"Vibrant", "Monochrome"}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 20):

For ease of direct access I have found through digging the following relationships for indexed colors:

```
map = {"Default" -> 97, "Earth" -> 98, "Garnet" -> 99, "Opal" -> 100, "Sapphire" -> 101, 
   "Steel" -> 102, "Sunrise" -> 103, "Textbook" -> 104, "Water" -> 105, 
   "BoldColor" -> 106, "CoolColor" -> 107, "DarkColor" -> 108, "MarketingColor" -> 109, 
   "NeonColor" -> 109, "PastelColor" -> 110, "RoyalColor" -> 111, "VibrantColor" -> 112, 
   "WarmColor" -> 113};
```

For example:

```
ColorData["Sunrise" /. map, "ColorList"]
```

[image]

Visually:

[image]

(`"Default"` was added manually; it is not listed with the others that I can find.)

In addition to indexed colors each of these PlotThemes has rules for gradient colors, Financial plots, Wavelet plots etc.  For example `"MarketingColor"` and `"NeonColor"` use the same indexed color scheme but other details are different.

This additional data may be conveniently found as follows.  (You will need [`step`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/1447/121).)

```
Plot[x, {x, 0, 1}]; (* preload PlotThemes system *)

System`PlotThemeDump`resolvePlotTheme["BoldColor", ""] // step

System`PlotThemeDump`resolvePlotTheme["Sunrise", ""]   // step
```

[image]

You can copy values directly or let the `Switch` statement assign the value to the appropriate Symbol.
For example to find the gradient colors used by:

```
BarChart[{Range@98}, PlotTheme -> "DarkColor"]
```

[image]

We can use this:

```
System`PlotThemeDump`resolvePlotTheme["DarkColor", ""];

System`PlotThemeDump`$ThemeColorGradient
```

[image]

You can of course view all definitions at once but be warned that it is long:

```
?? System`PlotThemeDump`resolvePlotTheme
```

This Symbol can also used to customize plot themes as I described in the second half of my answer to:

- [Is it possible to define a new PlotTheme?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/54545/is-it-possible-to-define-new-plottheme/54637#54637)