# Match colors to plot themes

Tags: plotting, color, legending

How do I get the colors to match the plot theme when I use a `PlotLegend` that is separate to the plots?
I have had a look at [How to access new colour schemes in version 10?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/54486/how-to-access-new-colour-schemes-in-version-10) but can't seem to find what I need.
Here is some data and an array of plots.

#### Initialization

```
data1 = 
 {Table[{x, Sin[x]}, {x, 0, 2 π, 0.1}], 
  Table[{x, Sin[2 x]}, {x, 0, 2 π, 0.1}], 
  Table[{x, Sin[3 x]}, {x, 0, 2 π, 0.1}]};

data2 = 
 {Table[{x, BesselJ[1, x]}, {x, 0, 2 π, 0.1}], 
  Table[{x, BesselJ[2, 2 x]}, {x, 0, 2 π, 0.1}], 
  Table[{x, BesselJ[3, 3 x]}, {x, 0, 2 π, 0.1}]};

data3 = 
 {Table[{x, BesselJ[4, x]}, {x, 0, 2 π, 0.1}], 
  Table[{x, BesselJ[5, 2 x]}, {x, 0, 2 π, 0.1}], 
  Table[{x, BesselJ[6, 3 x]}, {x, 0, 2 π, 0.1}]};

data4 = 
 {Table[{x, BesselJ[7, x]}, {x, 0, 2 π, 0.1}], 
  Table[{x, BesselJ[8, 2 x]}, {x, 0, 2 π, 0.1}], 
  Table[{x, BesselJ[9, 3 x]}, {x, 0, 2 π, 0.1}]};

opts = 
 {Frame -> True, Axes -> False, 
  FrameLabel -> {"Time/s", "Pressure/Pa"}, ImageSize -> 280, 
  BaseStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Times", FontSize -> 12}, 
  PlotTheme -> "Scientific"};
```

#### Result

```
Column[
  {Row[
    {Style["Data from experiment 5B", FontFamily -> "Times", 
     FontSize -> 12]}, Alignment -> Center, ImageSize -> (4 + 4 + 0.5) 72],
   Row[
    {ListLinePlot[data1, opts], Spacer[0.5 72], ListLinePlot[data2, opts]}],
   Row[
    {ListLinePlot[data3, opts], Spacer[0.5 72], ListLinePlot[data4, opts]}],
   Row[
    {LineLegend[{Red, Blue, Green},
    {"x-direction", "y-direction ", "z-direction"},
    LegendLayout -> "Row", LabelStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Times", FontSize -> 12}]}, 
   Alignment -> Center, ImageSize -> (4 + 4 + 0.5) 72]}
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

My problem is that I have the wrong colors in the caption.  How do I pick up the colors of the ***PlotTheme***?
I am using rows and columns rather than `GraphicsGrid` because I need to use the "Get Coordinates" feature using the right mouse click. `Graphics` grid does not permit this for individual graphs.

Comment: Add `PlotStyle -> {Red, Blue, Green}` to your `opts` variable. (Or choose whatever colors you want, so long as they agree with the choice in the `LineLegend`.)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use

```
colors=(("DefaultPlotStyle"/.(Method /. 
     Charting`ResolvePlotTheme["Scientific" ,  ListLinePlot]))/. Directive[x_,__]:>x)
```

to get the colors used in the `"Scientific"` plot theme. Then use `colors` as the first argument of `LineLegend`:

```
Column[{
 Row[{Style["Data from experiment 5B", FontFamily -> "Times", 
 FontSize -> 12]}, Alignment -> Center, 
 ImageSize -> (4 + 4 + 0.5) 72],
 Row[{ListLinePlot[data1, opts], Spacer[0.5 72], 
 ListLinePlot[data2, opts]}],
 Row[{ListLinePlot[data3, opts], Spacer[0.5 72], 
ListLinePlot[data4, opts]}],
 Row[{LineLegend[colors, {"x-direction", "y-direction ", 
  "z-direction"}, LegendLayout -> "Row", 
 LabelStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Times", FontSize -> 12}]}, 
  Alignment -> Center, ImageSize -> (4 + 4 + 0.5) 72]
  }]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks this sorts out my problem.

Comment: @Hugh, my pleasure. Thank you for the accept.

Answer (score 6):

This is not another answer but rather an extension of *kguler*'s correct response. Further issues are also identified.  In order to help use *kguler*'s answer I have made a function which may be useful to others.

```
ClearAll[plotColors];
plotColors::usage = 
 "plotColors[plotType,plotTheme] gives a list of the colors used in \
a plot when several curves are drawn. Here plotType is, for example, \
Plot or ListLogPlot while plotTheme may be \"Scientific\", \
\"Classic\" etc.";

plotColors[plotType_, plotTheme_] := 
 ("DefaultPlotStyle" /. (Method /. 
   Charting`ResolvePlotTheme[plotTheme, plotType])) /. Directive[x_, __] :> x
```

This function gives a nice list of colors when implemented, for example

```
plotColors[Plot, "Scientific"]
plotColors[ListLogPlot, "Scientific"]
plotColors[ListLinePlot, "Classic"]
```

Giving

[image: *Mathematica* graphics]

Another nice feature is that all the colors are listed but there is no need to reduce the number to that needed. This is done automatically.

For some plots my function does not work. For example for `ParametricPlot` there is both a `DefaultBoundaryStyle` and a `DefaultPlotStyle` covering the cases where a parametric region is plotted as an alternative to a curve. This may be discovered by typing

```
Charting`ResolvePlotTheme["Scientific", ParametricPlot]
```

Which gives

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Clearly `` Charting`ResolvePlotTheme `` is a function that needs to be explored.

Answer (score 6):

I propose using the [lower-level](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/54637/121) `` System`PlotThemeDump`resolvePlotTheme `` to find the information you need.  This reveals the color scheme number itself rather than resolving to a list of Directives.

You must give the plot function name as a String. The key you are looking for is `"DefaultColor"`:

```
Themes`ThemeRules;  (* preload PlotThemes subsystem *)

"DefaultColor" /. 
   Last /@ System`PlotThemeDump`resolvePlotTheme["Scientific", "ListLinePlot"]
```

> ```
> 108
> ```

That is all you need in your `LineLegend` to get the color scheme you want:

```
LineLegend[108, {"x-direction", "y-direction ", "z-direction"},
 LegendLayout -> "Row", LabelStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Times", FontSize -> 12}]
```

[image]

Comment: BTW, I would like to know that how do you know the **internal auxiliary functions** like  ``System`PlotThemeDump`resolvePlotTheme ``, ``Macros`SetArgumentCount``, ``Graphics`ArrayPlotDump`Private`hiddenOptions``. THX:-)

Comment: @ShutaoTang In many cases it took a lot of tedious digging through `Trace` results, but more recently often from an easier but still at times complicated task of reading top-level definitions with `Spelunk` or `PrintDefinitions`; see [What is the most convenient way to read definitions of in-memory symbols when we don't have the source files? (Spelunking tools)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1742/121)

Comment: @Shutao, to start you off on the wonderful world of "spelunking", look at the result of `Contexts[]`. You'll see a bunch of other contexts in there, each context having its own set. Then, you just try things out...

Comment: @ShutaoTang When you're feeling lucky, things like ``? *`*PlotTheme*`` sometimes strike gold.  Note though that some functions aren't loaded until needed.  So you should execute a dummy command, in this case a plotting command like `Plot[1, {x, 0, 1}]`, to search the full functionality.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard In re the last point in my comment, the same applies to ``System`PlotThemeDump`resolvePlotTheme["Scientific", "ListLinePlot"]``, which won't work until a plotting command has loaded `resolvePlotTheme`.

Comment: @MichaelE2 (and J.M.) I don't favor that approach.  Yes, at times its the only way to find something, and you just have to go out on a limb and try it as I did for [(88790)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/88790/121), but often the only way I can figure out what Symbol is or does is to see it used somewhere in a `Trace` or internal definition.  I think one could waste *a great deal of time* trying to browse Symbol names directly.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Regarding preloading, I've forgotten to include that before. Thanks.  Some of the stuff I load at start-up causes a limited amount of preloading so sometimes I don't notice this even if I start in an otherwise fresh kernel.

Comment: You're welcome. -  Re spelunking, I agree with you about the value of `Trace`, but it too can use a lot of time.  Knowing what to put in the second argument can be helpful. Certainly some ``? *`*foo*`` searches result in a large number of fruitless dead-ends. Good judgment, although not always easy to exercise, can allow you "to play your stones lightly," as they say in Go.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Thank  you for revisiting my old question. You have simplified and added more. Many thanks.