# Combining PlotThemes, PlotMarkers and Plot with MaTeX used on Labels, Axis Labels and Legend

Tags: plotting, legending, matex, marker

### Summary

I am currently attempting to make some of my earlier plots more fit for black-and-white printing, while keeping color and typesetting in TeX/Latin Modern Roman. While at it, I tried to highlight certain data points by adding PlotMarkers to both legend and plot.

Very close to what I wanted was the answer given for the question [How to use PlotMarkers or Mesh with Plot to creat Marks on the plot](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/80700/74972), but I have a lot of trouble getting MaTeX to work with it. So far, I lose both my axis labels and the plot markers (as they can be seen in the linked answer) in the legend.

### Details

I'm currently basing it all on the first suggestion of that answer, because I have trouble even understanding what the second part is doing, as I'm still somewhat new to Wolfram's syntax. Adding to that the warnings of Michael E2 regarding his own suggestion, I thought the first is probably a safer bet, anyway. I might be wrong here, so if my goal is more easily reached with the second idea, help with that would be appreciated.

This is what I managed:

```
ClearAll[markerMesh]; 
SetAttributes[markerMesh, HoldAll];
Needs["MaTeX`"]
texStyle = {FontFamily -> 
   "Latin Modern Roman 7"};(* This may need changing depending on the \
OS and its naming of Latin Roman fonts.*)
markerMesh[Plot[fns_List, {x_, x1_, x2_}, opts : OptionsPattern[]], 
  markerOpts : OptionsPattern[]] :=
 Show[
  Plot[fns, {x, x1, x2},
   Evaluate@FilterRules[{opts}, Except[{Mesh}]],
   PlotLegends -> {MaTeX["\\eta=1"], MaTeX["\\sin(D)"], 
     MaTeX["\\cos(D)"], MaTeX["\\log(D)"], MaTeX["J_0(D)"]},
   AxesLabel -> {MaTeX["D"], MaTeX["\\eta"]}],(* Plot Options End; 
  Here I get the Legend TeXed*)
  ListPlot[MapThread[
    Table[{x, #}, {x, 
       Replace[#2, 
        n_Integer :> 
         Rescale[N@Range[1, n], {0, n + 1}, {x1, x2}]]}] &, {fns, 
     PadRight[{}, Length[fns], 
      Replace[OptionValue[Plot, {opts}, Mesh], n_Integer :> {n}]]}], 
   FilterRules[{opts}, Options[ListPlot]],
   FilterRules[{markerOpts}, Except[{PlotLegends}]]],(* 
  ListPlot Options End*)
  ListLinePlot[{{}, {}}, FilterRules[{opts}, Options[ListPlot]], 
   markerOpts],(*ListLinePlot Options End *)
  BaseStyle -> texStyle,
  LabelStyle -> {}](* Show Options End; End markerMesh definition*)
markerMesh[Plot[{1, Sin[D], Cos[D], Log[D], BesselJ[0, D]}, {D, 3, 16},
   PlotRange -> Full,
  GridLinesStyle -> Directive[Dotted, Gray],
  GridLines -> Automatic,
  PlotTheme -> {"Detailed", "Monochrome", "ThickLines", "Vibrant"},
  Mesh -> {Range[3, 16, 1], Range[3, 16, 1], Range[3, 16, 1], 
    Range[3, 16, 1], Range[3, 16, 1]}],(* End inner plot options*)
 PlotMarkers -> {Automatic, 16},
 BaseStyle -> {}]
```

[image: The resulting figure.]

So far, I have not managed to get either the PlotMarkers back into the legend, nor the axis labels, at all. Depending where I change what and in what combination, very unexpected behavior occurs. Deleting the last BaseStyle, for example, changes the marker color to black.

Related: At some point, I intend to start changing which ticks appear on the x-axis (what I labelled "D"), but given my rather erratic trial-and-error for just the typesetting: How can I decide where this would have to be included as an option? For example, only with trial-and-error did I learn that the option `ImageSize -> Automatic -> 1024` would have to be added to the `Plot` when `markerMesh` is called, not as an option to `markerMesh` itself.

### Questions

- How to get the plot markers back into the legend?
- How to have axis labels?
- Bonus: Explanation/Guidance on how to decide which options (or combination of options) to change when further changing the plot...