# Extracting Color Options from BarChart

Tags: options, charts

I would like to extract the colors (i.e., obtain `RGBColor[]` or other full specification) of the different colors used in a bar chart such as this

```
BarChart[{{4, 4, 1, 0.05}, {3, 3, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 2, 2}, {2, 2, 4, 4}}]
```

for use in other figures, text and such.  I've tried `Options[BarChart]` and `AbsoluteOptions[...]` and found only that the options are `Automatic`.  I have also looked at a number of other posted problems focusing on extracting specific numerical `Option` values when the value is `Automatic` and none yield the answer.  Likewise controlling colors in `BarChart` is straightforward and not the problem I'm addressing.

Comment: `Union@Cases[BarChart[....], _RGBColor, Infinity]` is a first step ...

Comment: The default colors are `ColorData[97]`.

Comment: @rcollyer Thanks so much.  How did you find out that the default colors are `ColorData[97]`?

Comment: @DavidG.Stork I work at wolfram. :)

Comment: @rcollyer  OK, then... how do the *rest* of us find default values, such as colors?

Comment: @DavidG.Stork This [answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/56602/52) by MrW does a pretty good job at spelunking for that info.

Comment: Related, possible duplicate: [(66923)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/66923/121)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
bar = 
 BarChart[{{4, 4, 1, 0.05}, {3, 3, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 2, 2}, {2, 2, 4, 4}}]
```

[image]

```
c = Cases[bar[[1]], _RGBColor, Infinity]
```

[image]

```
Union@c // InputForm
```

> {RGBColor[0.4992, 0.5552, 0.8309304], RGBColor[0.7116405333333333,
>   0.4816, 0.5483194666666666], RGBColor[0.928, 0.5210666666666667, 0.2], RGBColor[0.982864, 0.7431472, 0.3262672]}

Comment: Thanks very much.  I think *Mathematica* should allow access to colors and other `Automatic` options directly, but your solution works perfectly.

Comment: Colors are not part of options but buried deep inside the graphic directives. I agree that there should be an easier way to identify the color scheme(s) used for a plot. Thanks for accept :)

Comment: A followup question:  Is there a way to extract the color *scheme* under such circumstances?

Answer (score 3):

You can find the actual default style information using this:

```
Charting`ResolvePlotTheme["Default", BarChart]
```

> ```
> {{0.71, "DefaultChartBaseStyle" -> RGBColor[0.982864, 0.7431472, 0.3262672]}, {0.1, 
>   GridLinesStyle -> Directive[
> GrayLevel[0.5, 0.4]]}, {0.71, 
>   "ChartDefaultStyle" -> (Blend[
>       Lighter[System`PlotThemeDump`$ThemeDefaultGradient, 0.2], #1] &)}, {0.1, 
>   "AxisPadding" -> Scaled[0.02]}, {0.1, "DomainPadding" -> Scaled[0.02]}, {0.1, 
>   "RangePadding" -> Scaled[0.05]}}
> ```

The key function:

```
stylefn = (Blend[Lighter[System`PlotThemeDump`$ThemeDefaultGradient, 0.2], #1] &);
```

And four styles as used in the chart:

```
Array[stylefn, 4, {0, 1}]
```

> ```
> {RGBColor[0.982864, 0.7431472, 0.3262672],
>  RGBColor[0.928, 0.5210666666666667, 0.2],
>  RGBColor[0.7116405333333333, 0.4816, 0.5483194666666666],
>  RGBColor[0.4992, 0.5552, 0.8309304]}
> ```

References:

- [How to access new colour schemes in version 10?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/54486/121)
- [Is it possible to define a new PlotTheme?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/54545/121)
- [What are the standard colors for plots in Mathematica 10?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/54629/121)