# default color scheme in `Histogram` in version 10

Tags: color, options, histograms

I need to use the default scheme of `Histogram` in version 10 but cannot get this information.
I know the default scheme used in `Plot`-like functions is `ColorData[97]`, but it seems `Histogram` uses a different one.
I tried `Options` which didn't help too much.

Can someone offer a hint?

Comment: Thanks! This helped me out: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/66982/260, but in which the extraction key should be changed to `ChartDefaultStyle`.

Comment: @sunt05 - you should post the answer here so it doesn't stay open as an unanswered question.

Comment: @JasonB, done. But I cannot find the code/name of this colour scheme, which seems to be a unique one and not an embedded entry in the `ColorData` collection.

Comment: @Michael I favor closing this as a duplicate of [(54486)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/54486/121).  Also related: [(54545)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/54545/121),
[(54629)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/54629/121),
[(66923)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/66923/121),
[(103829)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/103829/121)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Yes, ``Charting`ResolvePlotTheme[ChartStyle, Histogram]`` adapted slightly from your `PieChart` example leads to a solution here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to the [method here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/66982/260), with a minor modification for charts, we can get the answer as follows:

```
ClearAll[chartColors];
chartColors::usage="plotColors[plotType,plotTheme] gives a list of the colors used in a plot when several curves are drawn. Here plotType is, for example, Plot or ListLogPlot while plotTheme may be \"Scientific\", \"Classic\" etc.";

chartColors[chartType_,plotTheme_]:=("ChartDefaultStyle"/.(Method/.Charting`ResolvePlotTheme[plotTheme,chartType]))/.Directive[x_,__]:>x
```

The output is:

[image]

I then tried to look for the name/code of this scheme (something like `ColorData[97]`) but didn't get anything.

---

**update:**
As @JasonB pointed out, the only difference between `ColorData[97]` and the default colour scheme of `Histogram` is the yellow colours and their sequence:

```
cl1=chartColors[Histogram,$PlotTheme];
cl2=ColorData[97,"ColorList"];
Complement[#,Intersection[cl1,cl2]]&/@{cl1,cl2}
```

The output is:

[image]

I cannot understand why WR would break the consistency in default colour schemes of plots/charts functions, in particular the change in colour sequence.

Comment: Look at the output of `Thread[{chartColors[Histogram, "Default"]
  , ColorData[97] /@ Join[{2, 1}, Range[3, 15]]}]`, it looks like they just switch the first two colors, but it isn't quite true.  That yellow color for the histogram is *slightly* different than the default second plotting color.

Comment: Yes, @JasonB, the change in colour is minimal. And I don't understand why WR would change the sequence.

Comment: Merely a guess, but perhaps this scheme was hard-coded before `ColorData[97]` was defined?  Or perhaps someone in charge of `Histogram` thought that 97 needed adjustment and slipped this in?

Comment: Anyway, this consistency devalues the beauty of Mathematica to me.

Comment: I am afraid I cannot help you see *Mathematica* as more beautiful, but you can modify the `Histogram` colors if you like, to use `ColorData[97]` instead.  Would you like help with that?

Comment: Just a note, the second example in the documentation under `Histogram` (multiple data sets) does not match the output in v12.1, as these colors are NOT reversed.