# Problem with PlotLegends in Manipulate

Tags: plotting, manipulate, legending, scoping

Please consider this simple code:

```
Manipulate[
 Plot[{a Sin[x], a Cos[x]}, {x, 0, 2 Pi}, 
  PlotLegends -> "Expressions"], {a, 1, 2}]
```

*Mathematica* returns this output:

[image]

I believe this is a bug. Is there any workaround to cope with this problem?

I use *Mathematica* version 10.3.1 on Win 10 64bit. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The FrontEnd has the habit of renaming variables, which is usually a good thing, but sometimes can be troublesome. 
One possibility is to evaluate the argument of `Plot`, e.g.:

```
Manipulate[
   NumberForm[
       Plot @@ {{a Sin[x], a Cos[x]}, 
                {x, 0, 2 Pi},
                 PlotLegends -> "Expressions", 
                 PlotRange -> {-2, 2}}, {4, 3}
    ], 
    {a, 1., 2, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

[image]

Comment: The usage of `Appearance` is first time to me.I'm interested that how do you know it??

Answer (score 1):

Legends are heavily affecting the performance in `Dynamic` so I'd probably go with some hand made legends anyway:

```
Manipulate[
 Grid[{{
    Dynamic @ Plot[{a Sin[x], a Cos[x]}, {x, 0, 2 Pi}]
    ,
    LineLegend[
     {RGBColor[0.368417, 0.506779, 0.709798], RGBColor[0.880722, 0.611041, 0.142051]},
     TraditionalForm /@ {Dynamic[a Defer@Sin[x]], Dynamic[a Defer@Cos[x]]}
     ]
    }}], {a, 1, 2}]
```

> [image]

Colors for lines taken from [**Match colors to plot themes**](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/66923/5478)

Comment: Why not simply `Manipulate[
 Plot[{a Sin[x], a Cos[x]}, {x, 0, 2 Pi}, 
  PlotLegends -> {Dynamic[a Sin[x]], Dynamic[a Cos[x]]}], {a, 1, 2}]`. I got same result.

Comment: @Algohi I don't know how fast your machine is but on mine there is a noticable difference. The face that the `Plot` has to use `PlotLegends` slows it down a lot.