# Automatically coloring plot labels the same as the plotted curves

Tags: plotting, color, labeling

Here is an example of a `ListLinePlot`. How can get the text of the `PlotLabels` option to be the same as the colors automatically assigned to the curves by the `PlotTheme` option?

```
num = 10;
data1 = N@Sin@Range[num];
data2 = N@Cos@Range[num];
mark = ToString @@@ {Last@data1, Last@data2};

ListLinePlot[{data1, data2},
 Frame -> True,
 GridLines -> Automatic,
 GridLinesStyle -> Directive[Gray, Dotted],
 PlotRange -> All,
 PlotTheme -> "Web",
 PlotLegends -> Placed[SwatchLegend[mark], {Top, Left}],
 PlotLabels -> mark,
 InterpolationOrder -> 2,
 ImageSize -> Large
 ]
```

[image]

Although the user can do this mannually like this here,

```
{Style[text1, color1], Style[text2, color2]}
```

when data set count increases, it becomes increasingly more difficult to give the colors values that the PlotTheme option assigned.

Comment: Related: [(66923)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/66923)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I am eliminating what I consider extraneous details from your code, but I an generalizing the data to an arbitrary number of curves.

```
With[{nDiv = 10, nCurv = 3},
  data =
    Table[N @ Sin[u + h], {h, Subdivide[π/2, nCurv - 1]}, {u, Subdivide[2 π, nDiv]}]];

plt = ListLinePlot[data, PlotTheme -> "Web"];

lbls =
  MapThread[Style[Last[#1], #2, 14] &, {data, Cases[plt, RGBColor[__], ∞]}];

ListLinePlot[data,
  PlotTheme -> "Web",
  PlotLabels -> lbls,
  ImageSize -> Large]
```

[image: plot]

#### Update

The OP expresses worry about the performance cost of evaluating the plot twice. Since the 1st plot is not rendered to the screen, its evaluation is not as expensive as a fully rendered plot. However, if the data sets being plotted are very large, it might be profitable to restrict the 1st evaluation to the 1st three points in each data set. Like so:

```
With[{dta = Take[#, 3] & /@ data},
  plt = ListLinePlot[dta, PlotTheme -> "Web"]];
```

Comment: Great! but  ListLinePlot shall be executed twice, I doubt the performace go down.

Comment: why `plt/.{PlotLabels->lbls}` doesn't work?

Comment: @Jerry. Take a look at `FullForm[plt]`.

Comment: @Jerry. I don't know how to do it without re-evaluating the plot. However, when the plot is not rendered on the screen as in the 1st evaluation, it takes far less time than a rendered plot, so the performance hit is not as severe as you might think.

Comment: I see, thanks for your kind help;)

Comment: @Jerry You can avoid evaluating the plot twice, which is usually quick for `ListLinePlot` but not always quick for other plotter, with the following: ``theme = "Web"; styles = "DefaultPlotStyle" /. (Method /.  Charting`ResolvePlotTheme[theme, ListLinePlot]); lbls = MapThread[Style[Last[#1], #2, 14] &, {data,  PadRight[{}, {Length@data}, styles]}];``

Comment: @MichaelE2 It's great, thanks too! ;) I just see and use it on answer to this question https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/627/1-plot-2-scale-axis/186629#186629

Answer (score 2):

Very neat, but the proposed code seems to go wrong in Mathematica 12.0 because "Cases" gives a list of colours which is too long. Below an *ad hoc* solution which works here but I don't know how robust it is:

```
With[{nDiv = 10, nCurv = 3}, 
  data = Table[
    N@Sin[u + h], {h, Subdivide[π/2, nCurv - 1]}, {u, 
     Subdivide[2 π, nDiv]}]];

plt = ListLinePlot[data, PlotTheme -> "Web"];

lbls = MapThread[
  Style[Last[#1], #2, 14] &, {data, 
   Take[Cases[plt, RGBColor[__], ∞], Length[data]]}]

ListLinePlot[data, PlotTheme -> "Web", PlotLabels -> lbls, 
 ImageSize -> Large]
```

(Sorry I wanted to post as a comment but do not have permission.)