# Match light-shaded colors to plot themes for RegionPlot

Tags: color, regions, legending

I have a problem very similar to the one in the following topic: 
[Match colors to plot themes](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/66923/match-colors-to-plot-themes). I want to extract the color of a plot for the corresponding legend. However, as I use a RegionPlot I am interested in the color of the region.

[image: sample region plot]

However, when I use

```
Charting`ResolvePlotTheme["Scientific", RegionPlot]
```

I only get information on the color of the lines between the regions.

[image: output of charting command above]

Is there a way to extract the color of the regions?

Comment: I think it is just opacity setting. If you do the FullForm of the RegionPlot you will see something like: {EdgeForm[], Directive[FaceForm[Opacity[0.4`]], RGBColor[
 0.365248, 0.427802, 0.758297], AbsoluteThickness[1.6`], 
 Opacity[0.3`]],Polygon[…]}